# How to put these images together?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matlab-guide

I have `200` time points. For each time point, there is an image, the size of which is `40*40 double`, corresponds to this time point. For example, `image 1` corresponds to `time point 1`; `image k` corresponds to `time point k` (`k = 1,2,...,200`).

The time points are `T = 1:200`, with the images named as `Image_T`, thus `Image_1`, `Image_2` etc.

I want to put all these `200` images together. The final size is `40*40*200` double. The final image looks like fMRI image (`fmri_szX = 40`, `fmri_szY = 40` and `fmri_szT = 200`). How to achieve that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Dynamic variables

Note that whilst this is *possible*, it's considered to be bad programming (see for instance [here](http://matlab.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ#How_can_I_create_variables_A1.2C_A2.2C....2CA10_in_a_loop.3F), or [this blog by Loren](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/) and even the Mathworks in their [documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html?refresh=true) tell you not to do this). It would be much better to load your images directly into either a 3D array or a cell structure, avoiding dynamic variable names. I just posted this for completeness; if you ever happen to have to use this solution, you should change to a (cell-) array immediately.

The gist of the linked articles as to why `eval` is such a bad idea, is that MATLAB can no longer predict what the outcome of the operation will be. For instance `A=3*(2:4)` is recognised by MATLAB to output a double-array. If you `eval` stuff, MATLAB can no longer do this. MATLAB is an interpreted language, i.e. each line of code is read then ran, without compiling the entire code beforehand. This means that each time MATLAB encounters `eval`, it has to stop, evaluate the expression, then check the output, store that, and continue. Most of the speed-engines employed by MATLAB (JIT/MAGMA etc) can't work without predicting the outcome of statements, and will therefore shut down during the `eval` evaluation, rendering your code very slow.

Also there's a security aspect to the usage of `eval`. Consider the following:

```
var1 = 1;
var2 = 2;
var3 = 3;
varnames = {'var1', 'var2; disp(''GOTCHA''); %', 'var3'};

accumvar = [];
for k = 1:numel(varnames)
   vname = varnames{k};
   disp(['Reading from variable named ' vname]); eval(['accumvar(end+1) = ' vname ';']);
end
```

Now `accumvar` will contain the desired variable names. But if you don't set `accumvar` as output, you might as well not use a `disp`, but e.g. `eval('rm -rf ~/*')` which would format your entire disk without even telling you it's doing so.

**Loop approach**

```
for ii = 200:-1:1
    str = sprintf('Image_%d',ii);
    A(:, :, :, ii) = eval(str);
end
```

This creates your matrix. Note that I let the `for` loop run backwards, so as to initialise `A` in its largest size.

**Semi-vectorised approach**

```
str = strsplit(sprintf('image_%d ',1:200),' '); % Create all your names
str(end) = []; % Delete the last entry (empty)
%Problem: eval cannot handle cells, loop anyway:
for ii = 200:-1:1
    A(:, :, :, ii) = eval(str{ii});
end
```

`eval` does not support arrays, so you cannot directly plug the cellarray `str`in.

## Dynamic file names

Despite having a similar title as above, this implies having your *file names*  structured, so in the file browser, and not MATLAB. I'm assuming .jpg files here, but you can add every supported image extension. Also, be sure to have *all* images in a single folder and no additional images with that extension, or you have to modify the `dir()` call to include only the desired images.

```
filenames = dir('*.jpg');
for ii = length(filenames):-1:1
    A(:,:,:,ii) = imread(filenames{ii});
end
```

Images are usually read as `m*n*3` files, where `m*n` is your image size in pixels and the `3` stems from the fact that they're read as RGB by `imread`. Therefore `A` is now a 4D matrix, structured as `m*n*3*T`, where the last index corresponds to the time of the image, and the first three are your image in RGB format.

Since you do not specify how you obtain your `40*40` double, I have left the 4D matrix. Could be you read them and then switch to using a `uint16` interpretation of RGB, which is a single number, which would result in a `m*n*1*T` variable, which you can reduce to a 3D variable by calling `A = squeeze(A(:,:,1,:));`

Comment: Even in compiled languages, the outcome of `eval` may depend on the values of variables, and thus may not be predictable until run-time.