# Concatenation of N arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I want to do this with a shorter operation. How can i do it? Thank you

```
data = [Test1;Test2;Test3;Test4;Test5;Test6;Test7;---- until-----;Test36];
```

Comment: Why do your data look like that in the first place? If you explain where they comes from, it's possible there is a better way to create `data` earlier on...

Comment: Test1,Test2....are matrices 20x2 that i create in other function and i want to join the 36 matrices in 1 matrix 720x2

Comment: So don't create them as separate matrices. Make them part of `data` in the first place. Consider making it a *20*-by-*2*-by-*36* matrix. Then you can just use `reshape` to get it into your *720*-by-*2* form if you need to later. Don't clutter your workspace with many variables that really should all be in the same container

Comment: If you show us how you're generating the 36 matrices, we'll try to give you a more reasonable approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this using `eval`, however the use of this function is usually not recommended:

```
eval(['data=[', sprintf('Test%d;',(1:36)),'];'])
```

Rather follow Dan's comment and don't create seperate matrices.

Comment: This is a really bad idea in this case (in almost every case)

Comment: @Dan why is it a bad idea?

Comment: @Max check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32467029/how-to-put-these-images-together/32467170#32467170) and included links. They explain why using so-called "Dynamic Variable Names" is more or less the epitome of bad programming

Comment: @Max there are many articles online about this e.g. http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/. But in this case it is particularly poor advice because the solution is very clearly to have never created 36 different arrays in the first place. The OP has made a bad design choice which is easily rectifiable (note it's bad because it makes it extremely cumbersome to work with the data). This solution proposes a hacky work-around instead of addressing the root cause of the issue and recommending `eval` could cause miseducation.

Comment: ok, i got it, thanks

Comment: Upvoted because of your disclaimer.  I normally downvote `eval` questions because it's bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `eval` command to do this:

```
Test1=magic(5);
Test2=magic(5);
data=cell.empty(2,0);
for ii=1:2
    data{ii} = eval(sprintf('Test%d', ii));
end
```

Comment: What is `data=cell.empty(2,0);` for? I've never encountered this before, but when I test it, as soon as it runs `data{1} = ...`, `data` just becomes a *1*-by-*1* cell array so I can't see how it would help in terms of preallocation. Do you have a reference link to what `cell.empty` is for? I struggled to find it on Google...

Comment: I don't actually remember where i read it, but i read, that - in terms of efficiency - it's better to initialize a cell array outside of a for loop and you can do it by using `classname.empty`. Is that genereally wrong?
http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/empty.html

Comment: I don't know if it's wrong, but I don't know that it's right which is why I was hoping you a link. I'm not sure that it does do anything but maybe it does. It would be good to see confirmation though.