# Matlab group variables by similar names

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array of variable names that I want to plot.  For example,

```
var = {...
       'Xp_1';
       'Xp_2';
       'Xp_3';
       'PRES_1';
       'PRES_2';
       'PRES_3';
       'FLOW_1';
       'FLOW_2';
       'FLOW_3'};
```

Now, I want to group them by their names, that is, all Xps, PRESs, and FLOWs, and over-plot them on separate figure; thus, the total number of three figures: one for Xps, one for PRESs, and one for FLOWs.

I was brainstorming to do so by comparing the first two or three characters of all the variables.

How can I do this?

Comment: How did you end up with all those variables? This is called "Using dynamic variable names" and that is [bad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32467029/how-to-put-these-images-together/32467170#32467170)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [extract a substring](http://de.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/substring.html) and compare the results via logical operation or you can use [this method](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strncmpi.html).

```
figure(1); hold all; figure(2); hold all; figure(3); hold all;
for i = 1:length(var)
 if strncmpi('xp',var(i),2) // compare the first 2 characters
      figure(1)
       plot(eval(var(i))) // eval calls the variable by the name in var(i)
 elseif strncmpi('pr',var(i),2)
      figure(2)
       plot(eval(var(i)))
 elseif strncmpi('fl',var(i),2)
         figure(3)
       plot(eval(var(i)))
 else
  disp('No case for variable name');
end
```

Comment: Can you provide an example?  This isn't enough to answer the question.  There's a plotting element involved with this question too.

Comment: It's a simulation result with a model that has hundreds of parameter names.  I bring the simulation data as a struct and I do 'fieldnames' on it to get a cell array of variable names and 'struct2cell' to get a cell array of their time histories.  Then I '[ ]' them (let's call it 'data').  I do then plot(time_vector, data{i,2});ylabel(data{i,1}) in a while loop (time_vector is also extracted from data).