# How can I create a variable with a dynamic name based on a string in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, reflection, loading

I have the following MATLAB function that reads a variable `var`. For example, the struct `cfg` is passed as `var`. In this case, I succesfully recover this string representation as 'cfg' using `inputname(1)`. I can also succesfully save as 'cfg.mat'. However, loading into memory as 'cfg' does not work. I have considered using `eval`, but I have not been able to make it work.

```
function data_from_mat = optimize2disk( var )
%OPTIMIZE2DISK Saves a variable to disk, deletes it from current memory,
% and loads it from disk
%   
    tempvar = inputname(1);
    disp(['Saving ', tempvar, ' to disk...']);
    save([pwd, '\\', tempvar, '.mat']);    
    disp(tempvar);
    data_from_mat = load([pwd, '\\', tempvar, '.mat']);
end
```

Comment: Dont :(. Dynamic variables are not cool.

Comment: @AnderBiguri How is this helpful feedback? My goal is to reduce the probability of `OUT OF MEMORY` errors on a 32-bit system. Is there another way to solve my problem? `Pack` is not sufficient

Comment: So why do you save and then load back? Does that solve any of your problems? after the run of the code, the amount of memory is the same , rigth?

Comment: @noumenal this is as helpful as feedback can get. Not the answer to your specific question, but *very* helpful feedback.

Comment: @AndrasDeak What I mean by example: "GOTO statements are not cool. Don't do it." (not helpful, creates a different problem: refactoring) "Instead you have to..." (helpful: solves a problem) or "...should be avoided because..." (maybe not helpful but meaningful). Anyhow, the resulting answer was satisfying to my needs.

Comment: Check the links in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32467029/how-to-put-these-images-together/32467170#32467170), they explain quite well why using dynamic variable names and especially `eval` is bad. Gist: it breaks the interpreter and therefore all built-in acceleration engines

Comment: @Adriaan. Thanks, one of the sources says "don't create variables at runtime using EVAL unless you have a very good reason". In this case I was looking for a way to capture the passed reference and not the value. Java solves this thorugh reflection, so obviously if this functionality is implemented there are cases where it would make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To load it from memory do:

```
load([pwd, '\\', tempvar, '.mat']);
```

and it will load whatever it was inside with the names they were save with, or else do

```
data_from_mat=load([pwd, '\\', tempvar, '.mat']);
```

and `data_from_mat` will be a structure with fields corresponding to the name of the variables that were saved, thus

```
data_from_mat=getfield(data_from_mat,'varname'); %// instead of 'varname' tempvar?
```

will give you the data itself.