# how to use for loop to copy a 1 dimensional array to another array in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a data  of 512 bits, I want to slice it in 16 equal parts each of 32 bits. How can I do it in MATLAB using a `for` loop?

example:

```
inputdata=[1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0]
```

I want:

```
 outpu1=[1,0,1,0,0] output2=[0,0,0,1,1] output3=[1,0,0,1,0]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
inputdata=[1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0];
slices = 3; %// number of slices
slicelength = numel(inputdata)/slices;
kk=1;
for ii = 1:slices
    slicedarray(ii,:) = inputdata(kk:ii*slicelength);
    kk=ii*slicelength+1;
end
```

now `slicedarray` will contain your slices, with each row being one slice. You do not want the output variables like you asked for, because [dynamic variable names are bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32467029/how-to-put-these-images-together/32467170#32467170).

Vectorising stuff is faster in MATLAB, thus you can use `reshape`:

```
inputdata=[1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0];
slices = 3;
slicelength = numel(inputdata)/slices;
slicedarray(slices,slicelength)=0; %// initialise for speed
output = reshape(inputdata,[slices slicelength]);
```

In both cases the output is:

```
output =
     1     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     1     1
     1     0     1     0     0
```

Copyable for your benefit:

```
inputdata=rand(512,1);
slicelength = 16;
slices = numel(inputdata)/slicelength;
kk=1;
slicedarray(slices,slicelength)=0;
for ii = 1:slices
    slicedarray(ii,:) = inputdata(kk:ii*slicelength);
    kk=ii*slicelength+1;
end

output = reshape(inputdata,[slices slicelength]);
```

Comment: Thank Adriaan but i want slices to be stored in different variables, like out1, out2... till out16... I hope u now understnad what's my question.

Comment: I understand what you mean perfectly, but you do not want different variables. That's called using "dynamic variable names" which is very, very bad MATLAB practise, see the link I provided. I hope you understand what I mean now...

Comment: It's not just bad MATLAB practice, it's bad anything practice