# Naming veriable according to The index of The loop

Tags: matlab, variable-names

```
for i=1:1:4 
    T=[(cos(x(i)))^2 (sin(x(i)))^2 2*(cos(x(i)))*(sin(x(i)));(sin(x(i)))^2 (cos(x(i)))^2 -2*(cos(x(i)))*(sin(x(i))) ;-(cos(x(i)))*(sin(x(i))) (cos(x(i)))*(sin(x(i))) (cos(x(i)))^2-(sin(x(i)))^2 ;];
    XXXXX=inv(T)*Qq*R*T*inv(R);
end
```

I want to name `XXXXX` according to `i`; I mean that when `i=1` is running, The `XXXXX` will be variable `Q1`,and `i=2` will be `Q2`, and on and on.

Comment: I think you'll hve to use `eval()` for something like this.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to do this insteand of putting it in an array `Q{i}`?

Comment: You do not want these names. This is called using "Dynamic variable naming" and is considered [very bad practise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32467029/how-to-put-these-images-together/32467170#32467170). See the linked post for more info on why, and see Daniel's answer for the proper way of storing variables.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 While you can actually do this for performing what is exactly asked, it is a very bad idea to give such an answer for at least two reasons: first, the idea of the original poster is probably not the best and we have to explain the right way to do it; second, because using `eval()` isn't a good idea (unless we perfectly know why we are using it which wouldn't probably be the case here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [possible but not recommended](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html?refresh=true) to use variable names Q1 Q2 Q3. The link both explains why it is not recommended and how to implement it.

Instead, use a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) to store your results:

```
n=4; % or probably better n=numel(x)
Q=cell(n,1);
for i=1:1:4; 
    T=[(cos(x(i)))^2 (sin(x(i)))^2 2*(cos(x(i)))*(sin(x(i)));(sin(x(i)))^2 (cos(x(i)))^2 -2*(cos(x(i)))*(sin(x(i))) ;-(cos(x(i)))*(sin(x(i))) (cos(x(i)))*(sin(x(i))) (cos(x(i)))^2-(sin(x(i)))^2 ;];
    Q{i}=inv(T)*Qq*R*T*inv(R);
end
```

Comment: I plan on doing that but It gave me an error that Vector could not be a Matrix 3X3. Instead of That I created a 3d Matrix

Comment: If a 3d Matrix is possible, it is the better because faster choice. I was not sure if the result of each iteration is a matrix of the same size, thus suggested a more general solution which applies in any case.