# Calling workspace variables in a cell array

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have three variable stored in workspace like following

```
a = [1 2 4 8]
b = [4 9 3 8]
c = [8 6 4 2]
```

and I want to make a cell array of them and store it in x using a who command like

```
x = who
```

now a new cell array is stored as x that contains { 'a' 'b' 'c' }

but how can I call the values of variables stored in a
like x{1} returns me value 'a' and I want to get

```
[1 2 4 8]
```

as the result

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you really want to do this. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: It is indeed possible to do this, but, as @excaza points out, that's not really what you want. Why do you have these variables, why are they in your workspace and why do you want to call them? There's probably a better storage way with easy access, but we don't know until you tell us more.

Comment: I am developing a GUI and I have .mat file and I have to plot different graphs, for these graphs I want load these variables in popup menu and then plot the graphs

So I need help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rading the comment you should start in a different way. Use load with an output argument!

```
data=load(...)
```

This way all your data is stored in a struct called data with the field names a b and c. Now continue with your code:

```
%replacement for who, returning all field names
x=fieldnames(data)
%access first field using dynamic field names
data.(x{1})
```

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned in comments to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35022802/making-cell-array-of-all-variables-in-workspace-matlab) by @JohnHascall, @MatthiasW and @AndrasDeak, `x = who` would return you the list of variables in the form of cell array. There can be many different ways to record the values of those variables. I suggest to take advantage from the fact that the elements of `x` are strings, so we can access the values of the variables by using `eval` inside a loop:

```
x = who;
for ii = 1:numel(x)
    y{ii} = eval(x{ii});
end
```

The statement inside a loop would create another cell array and would record the values of corresponding variables. So, you would end up with something like this:

```
x = 

    'a'
    'b'
    'c'
    'd'
    'e'
y = 

[5]    'Hello'    [1x100 double]    [14x14 double]    [512x512x3 uint8]
```

So, suppose, you now wish to access `b(3)`. You would do it like this:

```
y{2}(3)

ans =

    l
```

Weird, but works anyway.

Comment: `eval` is a terrible suggestion

Comment: @excaza is a terrible commenter. Please, elaborate on why you don't like my suggestion

Comment: Because `eval` is a terrible function. The problem with that function is that it breaks *everything* in MATLAB. It can't compile your code any more, gives rise to all kinds of hard to find errors etc. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32467029/how-to-put-these-images-together/32467170#32467170) for a longer list of reasons why `eval` is indeed an evil function. Therefore I'd suggest setting a couple of warnings about the usage of `eval` around the post.

Comment: For a good reason the [documentation page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html) for the functions links alternatives to eval.