# Get output variable name from load function load in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to load an ASCII-file using this syntax:

```
load('10-May-data.dat')
```

The returned output variable name should be `X10_May_data`.

Is there a way to get the variable name in Matlab? If I want to use regular expression to do the translation, how can I do it? For example, put an `X` before any underscores or digits in the filename and replace any other non-alphabetic characters with underscores.

Comment: How was `'10-May-data.dat'` created? With `save`? Is it actually a MAT-file despite the extension?

Comment: And what does `s = load('10-May-data.dat')` return? Or are you just trying to do `fname = '10-May-data.dat';` `str = strsplit(fname,{'-','.'});` `vname = ['X' strjoin(str(1:end-1),'_')]`?

Comment: And if you are trying to do what @horchler said: please don't want to do that.

Comment: See: [dynamic field referencing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/) and [the documentation for `load`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`who`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/who.html) function returns the names of variables in matlab. It also has a built-in regexp for selecting certain items:

```
X10_May_data = [1 2 3];
save X10_May_data.mat X10_May_data
clear
load X10_May_data.mat
w = who('-regexp','X*')

w = 

    'X10_May_data'
```

You can then operate on `w{1}` to do any substitutions you want. For example, use the `strrep` function for simple modifications of a string:

```
newvar = strrep(w{1},'May','latest')

newvar =

X10_latest_data
```

For more complex modifications, use `regexp` or `regexprep`. When you have the new name, you can assign it with `eval`:

```
eval([newvar '=' w{1}])  % like typing "X10_latest_data = X10_May_data"

X10_latest_data =

    1     2     3
```

[edit] PS I agree with the comments that `eval` is usually a bad idea; but sometimes you just need to get *something done* :) For alternative approaches, see the [matlab page on the topic](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html).

Comment: [NOOOOO](https://static.squarespace.com/static/51b3dc8ee4b051b96ceb10de/51ce6099e4b0d911b4489b79/51ce61bde4b0d911b449f30f/1348785466046/1000w/Luke-No-Supercut-Star-Wars.jpg)

Comment: Using `eval` is almost always a terrible idea. Please see [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32467029/how-to-put-these-images-together/32467170#32467170) where I lengthily explain that.

Comment: RE: your edit. You can get *something done* just as quickly without using lazy code that is difficult for people to use/debug and impossible for MATLAB's JIT compiler to optimize.