# Regular expression MATLAB

Tags: regex, matlab

I have tried to solve this problem by reading old questions and by googles help.

I writing a short script in matlab where the user types in a equation and then plot the data by using eval.

But I want to check if the equation is right and uses the right variables and so...

I have three variables, X,Y,Z with upper case, so for example 'X+Y-Z-7.5' is a solid equation, but 'XB-Z' isn't. Just 'X' is also a solid "equation"...

How can I write the expression? Here is what I have...

```
regexp(test,'(X|Y|Z)$|(X|Y|Z|\d)&&(+|-|*|/|)')
```

My next plan is to do like,

```
if regexp(test,'(X|Y|Z)$|(X|Y|Z|\d)&&(+|-|*|/|)') == 1
    disp ('Correct')
end
```

So I want the regexp return if the string matches the whole expression, not just startindex. I have problem to fix that too.

Please, I'm stuck.

Comment: There are many useful web pages that help you generate regular expressions. I use the [Python version of Regular Expressions 101](https://regex101.com/#python), which pretty closely approximates MATLAB's syntax as well.

Comment: There are also 2 very different questions here. Testing for the presence of `X`, `Y`, and `Z` is straightforward, but using other criteria (what are those?) to test and see if the equation is 'right' is not necessarily a trivial task.

Comment: Save yourself some time, use `ezplot()` and `ezplot3()`

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution (if you have the Symbolic Math Toolbox) is to simply rely on that to determine whether the equations are valid.

You can use [`symvar`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symvar.html) to extract all symbols used in the equation and compare these to the variables you allow.

```
allowed = {'X', 'Y', 'Z'};
vars = symvar(userinput);

tf = ismember(vars, allowed);

if ~all(tf)
    disp('Invalid Variables Used');
end
```

This is likely going to be much more robust than attempting to create regular expressions as it relies on MATLAB's internal parser.

Comment: Using `eval` is a very bad idea and the more it can be avoided, the better. See [this answer of mine}(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32467029/how-to-put-these-images-together/32467170#32467170) for details and official documentation on why it should be avoided

Comment: @Adriaan while I completely agree, the user is already stating that he is using it to do his plotting.

Comment: @Adriaan - I use eval because I dont any other way around. I have a set of data, which I read into X,Y,Z. The user then type in what one want to plot, X+Y or just Y. How can I achieve the same thing without eval? So I have like,
X = rand(1,5)
Y = rand(1,5)
Z = rand(1,5)
Userinput = 'X+Y'

How can i plot this without using eval?

Comment: @Jocken that's a topic for another question. Ask one and someone with expertise in user interfaces in MATLAB can hopefully help you