# Understanding Non-homogeneous Poisson Process Matlab code

Tags: matlab, poisson

I have found the following Matlab code to simulate a Non-homogeneous Poisson Process

```
function x = nonhomopp(intens,T)
% example of generating a 
% nonhomogeneousl poisson process on [0,T] with intensity function intens

x = 0:.1:T;
m = eval([intens 'x']);
m2 = max(m); % generate homogeneouos poisson process
u = rand(1,ceil(1.5*T*m2));
y = cumsum(-(1/m2)*log(u)); %points of homogeneous pp
y = y(y<T); n=length(y); % select those points less than T
m = eval([intens 'y']); % evaluates intensity function
y = y(rand(1,n)<m/m2); % filter out some points
hist(y,10)

% then run
% t = 7 + nonhomopp('100-10*',5)
```

I am new to Matlab and having trouble understanding how this works.  I have read the Mathworks pages on all of these functions and am confused in four places:

1)  Why is the function defined as *x* and then the intervals also called *x*?  Like is this an abuse of notation?

2) How does the square brackets affect eval,

```
eval([intens 'x'])
```

and why is x in single quotations?

3) Why do they use *cumsum* instead of *sum*?

4) The given intensity function is `\lambda (t) = 100 - 10*(t-7) with 7 \leq t \leq 12`  How does `t = 7 + nonhomopp('100-10*',5)` represent this?

Sorry if this is so much, thank you!

Comment: That's a really strange piece of code. Do you have any inputs which make the function run without an error message?

Comment: Yes @Daniel, when I run it I get an error, but then running `t = 7 + nonhomopp('100-10*',5)` produces a histogram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. the function is not defined as `x`: `x` is just the output variable. In Matlab functions are declared as `function [output variable(s)] = <function name>(input variables)`. If the function has only one output, the square brackets can be omitted (like in your case). The brackets around the input arguments are, as instead, mandatory, no matter how many input arguments there are. It is also good practice to end the body of a function with `end`, just like you do with loops and if/else.
2. `eval` works with a string as input and the square brackets apprently are concatenating the string `'intens'` with the string `'x'`. `x` is in quotes because, again, `eval` works with input in string format even if it's referring to variables.
3. `cumsum` and `sum` act differently. `sum` returns a scalar that is the sum of all the elements of the array whereas `cumsum` returns another array which contains the cumulative sum. If our array is `[1:5]`, `sum([1:5])` will return 15 because it's 1+2+3+4+5. As instead `cumsum([1:5])` will return `[1 3 6 10 15]`, where every element of the output array is the sum of the previous elements (itself included) from the input array.
4. what the command `t = 7 + nonhomopp('100-10*',5)` returns is simply the value of time `t` and not the value of lambda, indeed by looking at `t` the minimum value is 7 and the maximum value is 12. The Poisson distribution itself is returned via the histogram.

Comment: Thank you @Alessiox; I think I understand the code better!  One last thing, why when I try `nonhomopp('10*-100',5)` this won't work?  So what if we we had an intensity function such as `x^2+x+10`, how would this be evaluated?

Comment: You have to carefully pay attention to the `eval` command. The `eval` command concatenates the string you give as 1st input with the string `x`. In this new case you concatenate `'10*-100x'`, but this is an invalid command in Matlab syntax. Even if you try running it in a regular way instead of `eval`, the syntax is invalid. `10*` means nothing, there's no second argument to that multiplication. Also `100x` is invalid because in Matlab you have to explicitly write down the `*` when evaluating multiplications.

Comment: Regarding the new intensity function you're proposing, that expression is not easy to concatenate and feed to `eval`. Also it depends, again, on what you feed to your function as first input parameter. That input must be concatenated in `eval`...that's the key. For more complex intensity functions, I recommend @Daniel's answer, with anonymous functions.

Comment: [Don't use `eval` ever](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32467029/how-to-put-these-images-together/32467170#32467170). Go with Daniel's suggestion of anonymous functions

Answer (score 3):

To answer 2). That's a unnecessary complicated piece of code. To understand it, evaluate only the squared brackets and it's content. It results in the string `100-10*x` which is then evaluated. Here is a version without eval, using an anonymous function instead. This is how it should have been implemented.

```
function x = nonhomopp(intens,T)
% example of generating a 
% nonhomogeneousl poisson process on [0,T] with intensity function intens

x = 0:.1:T;
m = intens(x);
m2 = max(m); % generate homogeneouos poisson process
u = rand(1,ceil(1.5*T*m2));
y = cumsum(-(1/m2)*log(u)); %points of homogeneous pp
y = y(y<T); n=length(y); % select those points less than T
m = intens(y); % evaluates intensity function
y = y(rand(1,n)<m/m2); % filter out some points
hist(y,10)
```

Which can be called like this

```
t = 7 + honhomopp(@(x)(100-10*x),5)
```

Comment: Thank you @Daniel, this is code makes much more sense!  I wish I could accept both answers, as this is just as helpful >.<