# Changing variable names dynamically

Tags: matlab, loops

I have a loop that calculates the mean (`m`), standard deviation (`std`), and standard error (`sem`) for multiple conditions. As each condition has its own `m`, `std`, and `sem` and I would like to name my output accordingly (they should be in double format). For example: `cond1_m`, `cond1_std`, `cond1_sem`, `cond2_m`, `cond2_std`, `cond2_sem` etc.

This is what I tried:

```
    cond={'cond1','cond2','cond3','cond4','cond5',...}
    for a=1:length(cond) 
        [strcat(cond{a},'_m'),strcat(cond{a},'_std'),strcat(cond{a},'_sem')]=compute_stats(M(:,a));
    end
```

Note: `compute_stats` is the function that outputs `m`, `std`, and `sem`. `M` is the matrix containing my data. The issue is that the `strcat` doesn't seem to work as a way of changing the name of my output. For iteration 1, for instance, instead of giving me `cond1_m`, my output is a matrix named strcat.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please [don't use `eval` in matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32467029/how-to-put-these-images-together). I suggest using a struct with dynamic field names, with syntax `condstruc.([num2str(a), '_m'])` etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider using a structure instead which is very suitable for your purposes. BTW, do not use `cond` as a variable name.  There is a function called [`cond`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cond.html) that calculates the condition number of a matrix. Using `cond` in this case would overshadow this function.  You can leave the `cond1`, `cond2`, etc. fields the way they are:

```
con={'cond1','cond2','cond3','cond4','cond5',...};
result = struct();
for a=1:numel(con)
    [m, stdd, sem] = compute_stats(M(:,a));
    result.([con{a} '_m']) = m;
    result.([con{a} '_std']) = stdd;
    result.([con{a} '_sem']) = sem;
end
```

`result` contains your desired compiled results.  You would then access the right matrix using the correct string name.  For example, if you wanted the `std` output for the first condition, do:

```
out = result.cond1_std;
```

Comment: Thank you. I did try to use a structure but insisted on using strcat (i.e., result.(strcat(cond{a},'_m') and clearly that didn't work.

Comment: @A.Rainer Ah :). Make sure you encapsulate the string with `[]` or it won't work when it comes to dynamically creating fields in structures.