# How to turn a string into a variable name within a loop?

Tags: matlab

I developed a matlab code that I now have to modify to turn into a loop. I would like to save my data at every iteration with a different variable name (without changing the variable name at the beginning of every iteration). Here I provide an example to explain what I want to do:

```
Matrix = rand(1000,3);
Dominated = 0;
Flag = 0;
k=0;
for k=1:10
   for i = 1:size(Matrix,1)
      Dominated = i
   end
    genvarname(sprintf('Dominated_%d',k)) = Dominated(:,:);
 end
```

however, if I execute this code, it does not provide me with a variable called "Domianted_1", "Domanted_2" and so on, but with a a variable called "genvarname" (replaced at every iteration) containing what was done into my code. How can I modify the code to get a different variable name at every iteration?

Comment: You don't want these variables. Save them in a matrix, a structure, or even a cell array, but don't use dynamic variable names. They are prone to errors, require [hackish tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32467029/how-to-put-these-images-together/32467170#32467170) or hand-copying lines and lines of code.

Comment: @Adriaan Just because it's bad programming practice, it does not justify a downvote for the question. (In case you did that, otherwise I'm sorry for my accusation)

Comment: Your sample code sets `Dominated(:,:)` to `1000` on every iteration. Is this really what you want to do? If not, what will be the actual sizes of `Dominated` that need to be stored? Will they all be the same size? Will the size change for different values of `k`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `assignin`, replace:

```
genvarname(sprintf('Dominated_%d',k)) = Dominated(:,:);
```

with

```
assignin('base',sprintf('Dominated_%d',k),Dominated(:,:));
```

---

But I recommend to rather use structs:

```
allDominated.(sprintf('Dominated_%d',k)) = Dominated(:,:)
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you I was not aware this function existed, and I am not used to work with structs even if in this case it is perfect