# Looping through a list of elements from the workspace in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops

In Matlab, I want to select by name and loop through some elements in the workspace, let's say for example these matrixes:

```
mymatrix1=ones(2);
mymatrix2=zeros(2);
mymatrix3=magic(2);
```

I can select them using `who`:

```
list_of_mymatrixes=who('mymatrix*');
```

to do some operation, for example write them to respective files:

```
for i=1:length(list_of_mymatrixes)
    x=strcat("my_matrix_number_",string(i));
    dlmwrite(x,list_of_mymatrixes(i,1));
end
```

but they are stored as just the variable name. `open('my_matrix_number_1')` shows `m,y,m,a,t,r,i,x,1`

So, which is the way to loop through these elements so that they are recognized as matrixes instead of strings (their names)?

Comment: Please don't use dynamical variable names.

Comment: While it may seem that the duplicate is answering another thing, it is not. You have a problem arising from a premise that is wrong, so the marked duplicate helps you fox that premise, instead of the problem caused by it.

Comment: you can access to the variables by using `eval`.

Comment: @OmG please don't.

Comment: I am compelled to use dynamical variable names. The set of matrixes I actually intend to use derives from manually choosing image points with the "cpselect" tool for image registration. I compare successive pairs of images, obtaining a pertaining matrix of "movingPoints" that I have to name each time.

Comment: @user3421755 use [a struct with dynamic field names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39959835/create-variables-for-indexing-in-matlab/39963723#39963723) instead. Whatever can be a variable name can also be a field name of a struct, but instead of having to kludge around with `eval` you can use the syntax `struc.('fieldname')`. If you start using dynamic variable names you set yourself on a path that's hard to get off of, and then you'll also say "I have to use dynamical field names because my data is set up like this..."