# How to show the result of a symbolic computation as a number?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, evaluation, equation-solving, newtons-method

I am solving an equation symbolically:

```
% Newton's method
syms x;
F(x)=x-cos(x);
FPrime(x)=diff(F(x));
display(FPrime(x));
x0=input('please give first point[x0] = ');
Accuracy=input('Accuracy[xn-xn-1] = ');
for k=0:15;
    x=x0-(F(x0)/FPrime(x0));
    x0=x;
    if(abs(F(x))<=Accuracy);
        display(x);
        break
    end    
end
```

I need `x` in as a real number but the answer comes out as `(cos(1) - 1)/(sin(1) + 1) + 1`. What do I need to do with this if I want a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting your output to `double` will produce to result you want:

```
x =

(cos(1) - 1)/(sin(1) + 1) + 1

>> double(x)

ans =

    0.7504
```

The above was tested on R2016b. If for some reason this doesn't work, there's the fallback of [`eval()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html), which produces the same result as `double()` (in this case).

Note that `eval` **can have various side effects** ([see example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32467170/3372061)) and should be used in extremely rare cases.

Comment: @MohammadrezaKhoshbin - Thank you for this comment. You are right that `vpa(x)` turns the `sin+cos` expression into a number, however the number is of type `sym`. I understood from the question that the OP wants "a real number", which to me is a `double`. Your suggestion may be equally valid - it's all a question of what the OP wants.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I didn't know about type of the resulting number.