# ODE45 with very large numbers as constraints

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, ode, ode45

2<sup>nd</sup> ODE to solve in MATLAB:

```
  ( (a + f(t))·d²x/dt² + (b/2 + k(t))·dx/dt ) · dx/dt - g(t) = 0
```

Boundary condition:

```
 dx/dt(0) = v0
```

where

- `t` is the time,
- `x` is the position
- `dx/dt` is the velocity
- `d2x/dt2` is the acceleration
- `a`, `b`, `v0` are constants
- `f(t)`, `k(t)` and `h(t)` are KNOWN functions dependent on `t`
  (I do not write them because they are quite big)

As an example, using symbolic variables:

```
syms t y
%% --- Initial conditions ---
   phi = 12.5e-3;
   v0 = 300;            
   e  = 3e-3;           
   ro = 1580;          
   E  = 43e9;   
   e_r = 0.01466;  
   B = 0.28e-3; 

%% --- Intermediate calculations ---
   v_T = sqrt(((1 + e_r) * 620e6) /E) - sqrt(E/ro) * e_r;
   R_T = v_T * t;                   
   m_acc = pi * e * ro *(R_T^2);  
   v_L = sqrt (E/ro);           
   R_L = v_L * t;    
   z = 2 * R_L;                   
   E_4 = B * ((e_r^2)* B * (0.9^(z/B)-1)) /(log(0.9));
   E_1 = E * e * pi * e_r^2 * (-phi* (phi - 2*v_T*t)) /16; 
   E_2 = pi * R_T^2 * 10e9;        
   E_3 = pi * R_T^2 * 1e6 * e;   

    %% Resolution of the problem  
        g_t = -diff(E_1 + E_2 + E_3, t); 

f(t,y)=(g_t - (pi*v_T*e*ro/2 + E_4) * y^2 /(y* (8.33e-3 + m_acc))];
fun=matlabFunction(f);
[T,Y]=ode45(fun,[0 1], v0]);
```

How can I rewrite this to get `x` as `y=dx/dt`? I'm new to Matlab and any help is very welcome !

Comment: So `t,g(t)` etc. are symbolic expressions, however the numerical integrator expects functions that can be evaluated for the float argument `t`. Does `vpa` do this conversion to a function definition? Something like (insert the correct function name) `g_func = @(tt) eval(g(t),tt)`?

Comment: If you have to use symbolic math for part of this, you need to convert symbolic functions and symbolic expressions to regular Matlab functions (or anonymous functions), as @LutzL alludes to. Use [`matlabFunction`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html) for this – [more here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/06/10/from-symbolic-differential-equations-to-their-numeric-solution/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First**, you chould use [`subs` to evaluate a symbolic function](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/use-subs-to-evaluate-expressions-and-functions.html). Another approach is to use [matlabFunction](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html) to convert all symbolic expressions to anonymous functions, as suggested by Horchler.

**Second**, you're integrating the ODE as if it is 1<sup>st</sup> order in `dx/dt`. If you're interested in `x(t)` as well as `dx/dt(t)`, then you'll have to modify the function like so:

```
fun = @(t,y) [y(2);   
             ( subs(g) - (b/2 + subs(k))*y(2)*y(2) ) / ( y(2) * (a + subs(f))) ];
```

and of course, provide an initial value for `x0 = x(0)` as well as `v0 = dx/dt(0)`.

**Third**, the absolute value of the parameters is hardly ever a real concern. [IEEE754 double-precision floating point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) can effortlessly represent numbers between `2.225073858507201e-308` and `1.797693134862316e+308` (`realmin` and `realmax`, respectively). So for the coefficients you gave (O(10<sup>14</sup>)), this is absolutely not a problem. You might lose a few digits of precision if you don't take precautions (rescale to `[-1 +1]`, reformulate the problem in different units, ...), but the relative error due to this is more than likely to be tiny and insignificant compared to the algorithmic error made by `ode45`.

`<RANDOM_OPINIONATED_RANT>`

**Fourth**, ***WHY*** do you use symbolic math for this purpose?! You are doing a *numerical* integration, meaning, there is no analytic solution anyway. Why bother with symbolics then? Doing the integration with symbolics (through `vpa` even) is going to be dozens, hundreds, yes, often even *thousands* of times slower than keeping (or re-implementing) everything numerical (which some would argue is already slow in MATLAB compared to a bare-metal approach).

Yes, of course, for this specific, individual, isolated use case it may not matter much, but for the future I'd strongly advise you to learn to:

- use *symbolics* for derivations, proving theorems, simplifying expressions, ...
- use *numerics* to implement any algorithm or function from which actual numbers are expected.

In other words, *symbolics* for **drafting**, *numerics* for **crunching**. And exactly *zero* symbolics should appear in any good implementation of any algorithm.

Although it's *possible* to mix them to some extent, that does not mean it is a good idea to do so. In fact, that's almost never. And the few isolated cases where it is the only viable option are not a vindication of the approach. 
They are rare, isolated cases after all, far from the abundant norm.

For me it bears resemblance with the evil [`eval`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html), with similar reasons for why it [Should.](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/) [Be.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32467170/1085062) [Avoided](https://24ways.org/2005/dont-be-eval/).

`</RANDOM_OPINIONATED_RANT>`

Comment: @JRM see my second point. If you want `x(t)`, then you need a 2ⁿᵈ initial value, namely, `x(0)`. Then just call `ode45(fun, [tstart,tend], [x0 v0]);`

Comment: @JRM see my second answer

Answer (score 0):

With the full code, it's easy to come up with a complete solution:

```
% Initial conditions
phi = 12.5e-3;
v0  = 300;
x0  = 0;    % (my assumption)
e   = 3e-3;
ro  = 1580;
E   = 43e9;
e_r = 0.01466;
B   = 0.28e-3;

% Intermediate calculations
v_T = sqrt(((1 + e_r) * 620e6) /E) - sqrt(E/ro) * e_r;
R_T = @(t) v_T * t;
m_acc = @(t) pi * e * ro *(R_T(t)^2);
v_L = sqrt (E/ro);
R_L = @(t) v_L * t;
z   = @(t) 2 * R_L(t);
E_4 = @(t) B * ((e_r^2)* B * (0.9^(z(t)/B)-1)) /(log(0.9));

% UNUSED
%{
E_1 = @(t) -phi * E * e * pi * e_r^2 * (phi - 2*v_T*t) /16;
E_2 = @(t) pi * R_T(t)^2 * 10e9;
E_3 = @(t) pi * R_T(t)^2 * 1e6 * e;
%}

% Resolution of the problem
g_t = @(t)  -( phi * E * e * pi * e_r^2 * v_T / 8 + ...  % dE_1/dt
               pi * 10e9 * 2 * R_T(t) * v_T + ...        % dE_2/dt
               pi * 1e6 * e * 2 * R_T(t) * v_T );        % dE_3/dt

% The derivative of Z = [x(t); x'(t)] equals Z' = [x'(t);  x''(t)]
f = @(t,y)[y(2);
          (g_t(t) - (0.5*pi*v_T*e*ro + E_4(t)) * y(2)^2) /(y(2) * (8.33e-3 + m_acc(t)))];

% Which is readily integrated
[T,Y] = ode45(f, [0 1], [x0 v0]);

% Plot solutions
figure(1)
plot(T, Y(:,1)) 
xlabel('t [s]'), ylabel('position [m]')

figure(2)
plot(T, Y(:,2)) 
xlabel('t [s]'), ylabel('velocity [m/s]')
```

Results:

[image: position as a function of time]
[image: velocity as a function of time]

Note that I've not used symbolics anywhere, except to double-check my hand-derived derivatives.