# Use the content of a cell as a label of a symbolic variable

Tags: matlab, command, symbolic-math

Can I do the following idea in Matlab command?
Assuming that

```
a = 'c1Tl';
```

class(a) will return cell.

How I can use the content of an as a cell variable which I can do

```
c1Tl = 3;
```

I try to use

```
sym(a) = 3;
```

to assign a variable to the content of 'a' but It is not my purpose.
Please help to solve my problem!
Thank you!

Comment: You really don't want those variables, as dynamic variable naming is [bad, very bad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32467029/how-to-put-these-images-together/32467170#32467170).

Comment: My purpose is made a script that can store the object after loading because I have many objects to load, the object is used in later. If I do not do so, I have to manually generate many variable names.

Comment: No you don't see the duplicate. Just use a structure data type. The answer you accepted (and thus hopefully use) doesn't use dynamically named variables either. Just stick with the structures.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do that is to use a struct data type. You would do something like this:

```
a = {'c1Tl'};
%Lets make a struct called data which will store the values
data.(a{1}) = 3; % The a{1} accesses the string stored in a and uses it to make a field in the structure data
%To access your data, now you can use
data.c1Tl
```

Comment: My purpose is made a script that can store the object after loading because I have many objects to load, the object is used in later. If I do not do so, I have to manually generate many variable names.