# name matrix as A1 to A50 automatically

Tags: matlab

I run an algorithm that result of it is a matrix as A. I run an algorithm 50 times and I want to save results as A1 to A50 matrix. how can I write?

Comment: You should really consider using a 3D array, or cell array of matrices.

Comment: You really don't want those variables, as dynamic variable naming is [bad, very bad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32467029/how-to-put-these-images-together/32467170#32467170).

Comment: What @OliverCharlesworth said, x1000.