# How to skip header lines while importing multiple text files?

Tags: matlab, matrix, import, text-files, matlab-figure

I have hundreds of text files that I need to import as individual matrices, but each text file has 6 rows of junk headers that I want to ignore/delete. The text files are tab delimited. I just need to import each file as a unique matrix from row 7 onwards. There are 149 columns in each file, and the length ranges from 400-1500 rows. How to do this? Also how would I plot, for example, the 5th column of each file onto the same plot?

---

This is what I'm currently trying to make work:

```
txtfiles = dir('*.txt');
numfiles = length(txtfiles);
for k = 1:numfiles
    %textscan(txtfiles(k).name)
    curname = txtfiles(k).name;
    FID=fopen(curname);
    datacell = textscan(FID, 'f%f%f%f', ...
    'HeaderLines', 6, 'CollectOutput', 1);
    fclose(FID);
    A = datacell{1};
end
```

This is what the text files look like:

```
PathFileType    4   (X/Y/Z) C:\Users\P\Desktop\Data\STS1.trc
DataRate    CameraRate  NumFrames   NumMarkers  Units   OrigDataRate    OrigDataStartFrame  OrigNumFrames
120.00  120.00         878  29  mm  120.00  1          878
Frame#  Time    Top.Head            Front.Head          Rear.Head           R.Shoulder          R.Offset            R.Elbow         R.Wrist         L.Shoulder          L.Elbow         L.Wrist         R.ASIS          L.ASIS          V.Sacral            R.Thigh         R.Knee          R.Shank         R.Ankle         R.Heel          R.Toe           L.Thigh         L.Knee          L.Shank         L.Ankle         L.Heel          L.Toe           R.Knee.Medial           R.Ankle.Medial          L.Knee.Medial           L.Ankle.Medial          V_Mid_ASIS          V_Pelvis_Origin         V_R.Hip_JC          V_L.Hip_JC          V_R.Knee_JC_Static          V_L.Knee_JC_Static          V_R.Ankle_JC_Static         V_L.Ankle_JC_Static         V_R.Knee_JC         V_L.Knee_JC         V_R.Ankle_JC            V_L.Ankle_JC            V_Mid_Hip           V_Mid_Shoulder          V_R.Hand            V_L.Hand            V_R.Toe_Offset_Static           V_L.Toe_Offset_Static           V_R.Toe_Offset          V_L.Toe_Offset          
        X1  Y1  Z1  X2  Y2  Z2  X3  Y3  Z3  X4  Y4  Z4  X5  Y5  Z5  X6  Y6  Z6  X7  Y7  Z7  X8  Y8  Z8  X9  Y9  Z9  X10 Y10 Z10 X11 Y11 Z11 X12 Y12 Z12 X13 Y13 Z13 X14 Y14 Z14 X15 Y15 Z15 X16 Y16 Z16 X17 Y17 Z17 X18 Y18 Z18 X19 Y19 Z19 X20 Y20 Z20 X21 Y21 Z21 X22 Y22 Z22 X23 Y23 Z23 X24 Y24 Z24 X25 Y25 Z25 X26 Y26 Z26 X27 Y27 Z27 X28 Y28 Z28 X29 Y29 Z29 X30 Y30 Z30 X31 Y31 Z31 X32 Y32 Z32 X33 Y33 Z33 X34 Y34 Z34 X35 Y35 Z35 X36 Y36 Z36 X37 Y37 Z37 X38 Y38 Z38 X39 Y39 Z39 X40 Y40 Z40 X41 Y41 Z41 X42 Y42 Z42 X43 Y43 Z43 X44 Y44 Z44 X45 Y45 Z45 X46 Y46 Z46 X47 Y47 Z47 X48 Y48 Z48 X49 Y49 Z49 

1   0.000   578.07806   1549.15051  -222.10861  582.42267   1488.45020  -150.36578  563.25293   1428.10291  -358.14984  424.26584   1281.06860  -338.22803  504.68622   1037.25378  -450.03931  322.89386   924.37604   -317.79419  321.13821   719.21008   -192.82649  722.02570   1291.98120  -345.90573  827.16968   932.11102   -315.86163  829.74890   713.94104   -204.21365  460.80588   849.29614   -259.36377  725.33618   849.07758   -321.35016  538.44873   850.64178   -472.68457  413.92474   755.16034   -34.96117   356.78342   656.36346   38.76009    374.58469   460.21146   19.69482    394.72556   281.48828   -82.69444   444.48990   253.92299   -143.76108  398.78040   239.94897   46.18449    730.78320   747.37939   -44.34066   774.68842   630.90723   47.31462    748.68585   441.55353   -4.17119    717.03888   277.31525   -98.16077   662.72064   257.86353   -148.39008  705.67841   240.00070   37.66716    468.87674   621.90070   59.08336    474.91696   291.71790   -58.21749   660.09216   626.54254   66.12887    638.38428   292.67764   -63.12149   593.07104   849.18689   -290.35696  579.43481   849.64166   -348.55203  494.55240   757.33771   -329.38379  663.85175   757.19788   -369.05505  412.83008   639.13208   48.92172    717.39026   628.72485   56.72174    434.82126   286.60309   -70.45597   677.71161   284.99643   -80.64113   414.15628   641.45532   60.94458    714.27588   615.87555   67.47660    438.84448   275.22925   -66.18838   676.67859   283.57892   -73.62092   579.20209   757.26776   -349.21942  573.14575   1286.52490  -342.06686  320.43594   637.14368   -142.83942  830.78058   626.67303   -159.55447  398.78040   239.94897   26.18449    705.67841   240.00070   17.66716    395.66873   220.34248   43.75488    705.05811   220.08913   35.89385    
2   0.008   578.07141   1549.15735  -222.12216  582.40057   1488.47058  -150.36993  563.27405   1428.09717  -358.14203  424.27509   1281.09106  -338.19501  504.68646   1037.27405  -450.02933  322.93146   924.38745   -317.75854  321.18677   719.21857   -192.83357  722.03998   1291.99280  -345.90076  827.16187   932.11371   -315.87897  829.68628   713.94934   -204.21298  460.82901   849.32904   -259.36237  725.33636   849.08423   -321.35602  538.43628   850.65222   -472.69458  413.93283   755.15924   -34.96411   356.79126   656.35864   38.75017    374.59924   460.20187   19.68288    394.73041   281.47412   -82.70995   444.49213   253.91530   -143.75822  398.79437   239.95001   46.18539    730.81970   747.38501   -44.35924   774.74005   630.90015   47.28659    748.67841   441.58804   -4.23859    717.04755   277.30865   -98.15942   662.73602   257.88791   -148.39410  705.69049   240.00151   37.66610    468.88843   621.90277   59.08383    474.90295   291.69644   -58.26284   660.19403   626.55139   66.12325    638.39575   292.68515   -63.12182   593.08270   849.20660   -290.35919  579.44489   849.65808   -348.54926  494.56226   757.36951   -329.37161  663.84698   757.21283   -369.04755  412.83984   639.13068   48.91700    717.46704   628.72577   56.70492    434.81668   286.58530   -70.48640   677.72162   284.99692   -80.64062   414.16898   641.45361   60.92418    714.29749   615.90765   67.38762    438.85022   275.22717   -66.20164   676.68585   283.58505   -73.62514   579.20465   757.29114   -349.20959  573.15753   1286.54199  -342.04788  320.48889   637.15100   -142.86359  830.69604   626.68359   -159.54659  398.79437   239.95001   26.18539    705.69049   240.00151   17.66610    395.68719   220.34254   43.75785    705.06299   220.09024   35.89198    
3   0.017   578.06696   1549.16443  -222.13680  582.38141   1488.49182  -150.37547  563.29578   1428.09131  -358.13553  424.28442   1281.11218  -338.16238  504.68698   1037.29321  -450.01859  322.96741   924.39795   -317.72415  321.23508   719.22565   -192.83934  722.05438   1292.00427  -345.89575  827.15356   932.11530   -315.89606  829.62433   713.95685   -204.21211  460.85236   849.36053   -259.36084  725.33704   849.09039   -321.36160  538.42535   850.66272   -472.70282  413.94089   755.15808   -34.96635   356.79880   656.35425   38.74130    374.61288   460.19308   19.67173    394.73553   281.46118   -82.72367   444.49405   253.90808   -143.75546  398.80777   239.95140   46.18635    730.85583   747.39014   -44.37709   774.79138   630.89276   47.25950    748.67249   441.62027   -4.30229    717.05573   277.30246   -98.15792   662.74878   257.91034   -148.39815  705.70233   240.00237   37.66516    468.90030   621.90460   59.08529    474.88895   291.67554   -58.30784   660.30164   626.56012   66.12052    638.40662   292.69202   -63.12206   593.09467   849.22546   -290.36121  579.45532   849.67389   -348.54636  494.57263   757.40039   -329.35986  663.84283   757.22742   -369.04037  412.84955   639.12939   48.91330    717.54651   628.72644   56.69001    434.81223   286.56836   -70.51575   677.73120   284.99722   -80.63999   414.18085   641.45203   60.90602    714.32013   615.93805   67.30240    438.85620   275.22488   -66.21367   676.69293   283.59100   -73.62849   579.20770   757.31390   -349.20010  573.16937   1286.55823  -342.02905  320.54214   637.15674   -142.88542  830.61261   626.69348   -159.53853  398.80777   239.95140   26.18635    705.70233   240.00237   17.66516    395.70450   220.34308   43.76075    705.06799   220.09137   35.89036    
4   0.025   578.06677   1549.17200  -222.15352  582.36774   1488.51465  -150.38351  563.31909   1428.08545  -358.13141  424.29370   1281.13074  -338.13037  504.68799   1037.31030  -450.00674  323.00058   924.40686   -317.69220  321.28256   719.22998   -192.84291  722.06866   1292.01489  -345.89114  827.14423   932.11481   -315.91281  829.56348   713.96271   -204.21091  460.87613   849.38965   -259.35883  725.33850   849.09552   -321.36685  538.41693   850.67303   -472.70807  413.94897   755.15680   -34.96721   356.80551   656.35059   38.73447    374.62491   460.18558   19.66194    394.74109   281.45056   -82.73444   444.49548   253.90161   -143.75296  398.82004   239.95326   46.18732    730.89136   747.39447   -44.39344   774.84204   630.88477   47.23421    748.66937   441.64847   -4.35954    717.06299   277.29691   -98.15623   662.75745   257.92950   -148.40205  705.71356   240.00327   37.66439    468.91217   621.90619   59.08857    474.87485   291.65567   -58.35194   660.42023   626.56854   66.12308    638.41656   292.69772   -63.12215   593.10730   849.24255   -290.36285  579.46637   849.68848   -348.54309  494.58374   757.42944   -329.34863  663.83966   757.24121   -369.03378  412.85886   639.12836   48.91152    717.63116   628.72668   56.67864    434.80798   286.55313   -70.54319   677.73981   284.99731   -80.63919   414.19101   641.45068   60.89182    714.34491   615.96490   67.22484    438.86258   275.22226   -66.22359   676.69971   283.59653   -73.63049   579.21167   757.33533   -349.19119  573.18115   1286.57275  -342.01074  320.59537   637.15924   -142.90320  830.53119   626.70190   -159.53015  398.82004   239.95326   26.18732    705.71356   240.00327   17.66439    395.71960   220.34428   43.76338    705.07306   220.09251   35.88912    
5   0.033   578.07257   1549.17993  -222.17319  582.36163   1488.53967  -150.39473  563.34473   1428.07947  -358.13049  424.30261   1281.14575  -338.09915  504.68936   1037.32483  -449.99374  323.03046   924.41333   -317.66357  321.32822   719.23065   -192.84392  722.08209   1292.02295  -345.88791  827.13342   932.11127   -315.92960  829.50409   713.96625   -204.20932  460.90021   849.41565   -259.35587  725.34064   849.09918   -321.37180  538.41180   850.68292   -472.70987  413.95694   755.15533   -34.96606   356.81076   656.34784   38.73051    374.63489   460.17975   19.65404    394.74686   281.44305   -82.74197   444.49646   253.89604   -143.75098  398.83054   239.95537   46.18819    730.92584   747.39801   -44.40755   774.89136   630.87616   47.21148    748.66968   441.67154   -4.40879    717.06909   277.29193   -98.15450   662.76141   257.94485   -148.40559  705.72375   240.00404   37.66366    468.92358   621.90765   59.09414    474.86066   291.63742   -58.39412   660.55341   626.57678   66.13264    638.42529   292.70221   -63.12214   593.12042   849.25739   -290.36383  579.47778   849.70142   -348.53928  494.59540   757.45612   -329.33768  663.83734   757.25360   -369.02789  412.86719   639.12775   48.91233    717.72241   628.72650   56.67206    434.80374   286.54022   -70.56805   677.74719   284.99707   -80.63832   414.19885   641.44983   60.88240    714.37201   615.98706   67.15769    438.86899   275.21948   -66.23103   676.70599   283.60150   -73.63105   579.21637   757.35486   -349.18277  573.19232   1286.58435  -341.99353  320.64731   637.15759   -142.91606  830.45233   626.70825   -159.52121  398.83054   239.95537   26.18819    705.72375   240.00404   17.66366    395.73163   220.34599   43.76553    705.07782   220.09349   35.88815    
6   0.042   578.08588   1549.18835  -222.19646  582.36450   1488.56677  -150.40939  563.37341   1428.07275  -358.13312  424.31094   1281.15662  -338.06894  504.69083   1037.33618  -449.97983  323.05698   924.41681   -317.63879  321.37064   719.22717   -192.84242  722.09406   1292.02686  -345.88690  827.12079   932.10400   -315.94684  829.44611   713.96692   -204.20734  460.92407   849.43811   -259.35126  725.34332   849.10107   -321.37613  538.41022   850.69202   -472.70807  413.96457   755.15375   -34.96246   356.81393   656.34583   38.72992    374.64261   460.17557   19.64865    394.75226   281.43909   -82.74693   444.49701   253.89154   -143.74985  398.83875   239.95750   46.18889    730.95892   747.40063   -44.41883   774.93866   630.86688   47.19197    748.67316   441.68939   -4.44986    717.07367   277.28741   -98.15311   662.76099   257.95660   -148.40849  705.73248   240.00450   37.66269    468.93372   621.90924   59.10220    474.84680   291.62143   -58.43286   660.70197   626.58490   66.15015    638.43298   292.70584   -63.12206   593.13373   849.26959   -290.36371  579.48914   849.71228   -348.53452  494.60715   757.47986   -329.32651  663.83551   757.26422   -369.02240  412.87381   639.12756   48.91606    717.82031   628.72589   56.67106    434.79953   286.53024   -70.58990   677.75336   284.99661   -80.63758   414.20404   641.44940   60.87769    714.40100   616.00409   67.10224    438.87469   275.21698   -66.23629   676.71143   283.60587   -73.63052   579.22131   757.37201   -349.17447  573.20251   1286.59167  -341.97791  320.69611   637.15131   -142.92387  830.37622   626.71210   -159.51154  398.83875   239.95750   26.18889    705.73248   240.00450   17.66269    395.74011   220.34798   43.76709    705.08179   220.09410   35.88714    
7   0.050   578.10748   1549.19727  -222.22368  582.37732   1488.59607  -150.42754  563.40497   1428.06494  -358.13873  424.31824   1281.16272  -338.03998  504.69205   1037.34448  -449.96536  323.08054   924.41681   -317.61798  321.40854   719.21924   -192.83867  722.10388   1292.02466  -345.88876  827.10596   932.09265   -315.96509  829.38910   713.96429   -204.20511  460.94684   849.45673   -259.34442  725.34625   849.10114   -321.37909  538.41217   850.70001   -472.70279  413.97162   755.15228   -34.95613   356.81467   656.34442   38.73293    374.64801   460.17297   19.64643    394.75650   281.43851   -82.75058   444.49722   253.88837   -143.74980  398.84448   239.95943   46.18940    730.99017   747.40265   -44.42699   774.98322   630.85742   47.17620    748.67883   441.70300   -4.48388    717.07666   277.28326   -98.15250   662.75714   257.96545   -148.41026  705.73944   240.00450   37.66124    468.94171   621.91095   59.11267    474.83340   291.60818   -58.46715   660.86237   626.59351   66.17556    638.43958   292.70929   -63.12188   593.14655   849.27893   -290.36176  579.49982   849.72095   -348.52823  494.61829   757.50031   -329.31458  663.83392   757.27271   -369.01675  412.87817   639.12769   48.92280    717.92279   628.72546   56.67588    434.79495   286.52335   -70.60886   677.75812   284.99628   -80.63718   414.20651   641.44940   60.87712    714.43079   616.01678   67.05805    438.87888   275.21555   -66.24011   676.71594   283.60971   -73.62940   579.22607   757.38654   -349.16565  573.21106   1286.59375  -341.96439  320.73975   637.14020   -142.92694  830.30237   626.71295   -159.50111  398.84448   239.95943   26.18940    705.73944   240.00450   17.66124    395.74524   220.34995   43.76808    705.08453   220.09424   35.88577    
8   0.058   578.13776   1549.20618  -222.25487  582.40051   1488.62708  -150.44893  563.43854   1428.05505  -358.14627  424.32397   1281.16406  -338.01248  504.69275   1037.34973  -449.95074  323.10150   924.41321   -317.60114  321.44086   719.20673   -192.83292  722.11096   1292.01538  -345.89407  827.08905   932.07697   -315.98495  829.33258   713.95844   -204.20287  460.96765   849.47150   -259.33499  725.34937   849.09961   -321.37979  538.41718   850.70697   -472.69437  413.97787   755.15112   -34.94693   356.81287   656.34351   38.73965    374.65121   460.17169   19.64787    394.75891   281.44086   -82.75436   444.49722   253.88678   -143.75089  398.84772   239.96091   46.18974    731.01935   747.40405   -44.43204   775.02429   630.84814   47.16449    748.68579   441.71371   -4.51204    717.07800   277.27963   -98.15291   662.75171   257.97250   -148.41019  705.74451   240.00403   37.65928    468.94693   621.91260   59.12523    474.82053   291.59775   -58.49672   661.02661   626.60321   66.20764    638.44537   292.71347   -63.12144   593.15851   849.28558   -290.35739  579.50958   849.72748   -348.51996  494.62836   757.51703   -329.30157  663.83264   757.27905   -369.01025  412.87988   639.12805   48.93244    718.02545   628.72565   56.68607    434.78973   286.51932   -70.62553   677.76172   284.99655   -80.63718   414.20651   641.44977   60.88002    714.46027   616.02570   67.02457    438.88083   275.21591   -66.24341   676.71942   283.61322   -73.62820   579.23053   757.39801   -349.15591  573.21747   1286.58972  -341.95328  320.77661   637.12415   -142.92563  830.22998   626.71100   -159.49004  398.84772   239.96091   26.18974    705.74451   240.00403   17.65928    395.74747   220.35156   43.76857    705.08588   220.09387   35.88390    
9   0.067   578.17651   1549.21521  -222.28969  582.43390   1488.65930  -150.47295  563.47302   1428.04272  -358.15457  424.32767   1281.16064  -337.98660  504.69287   1037.35193  -449.93646  323.12003   924.40582   -317.58804  321.46692   719.18964   -192.82539  722.11469   1291.99792  -345.90323  827.06995   932.05707   -316.00714  829.27631   713.94946   -204.20088  460.98596   849.48236   -259.32318  725.35254   849.09692   -321.37781  538.42450   850.71295   -472.68362  413.98325   755.15039   -34.93485   356.80856   656.34283   38.75000    374.65253   460.17136   19.65314    394.75928   281.44540   -82.75931   444.49719   253.88681   -143.75290  398.84872   239.96179   46.18988    731.04626   747.40515   -44.43405   775.06165   630.83972   47.15686    748.69373   441.72217   -4.53473    717.07782   277.27682   -98.15436   662.74664   257.97888   -148.40746  705.74792   240.00320   37.65699    468.94882   621.91400   59.13937    474.80859   291.59039   -58.52081   661.18463   626.61414   66.24427    638.45056   292.71918   -63.12055   593.16925   849.28967   -290.35049  579.51819   849.73193   -348.50974  494.63715   757.53015   -329.28775  663.83173   757.28345   -369.00269  412.87869   639.12842   48.94469    718.12311   628.72693   56.70057    434.78394   286.51788   -70.64006   677.76422   284.99799   -80.63745   414.20435   641.45044   60.88571    714.48901   616.03168   67.00146    438.88034   275.21832   -66.24689   676.72168   283.61658   -73.62720   579.23444   757.40680   -349.14520  573.22119   1286.57922  -341.94492  320.80566   637.10315   -142.92033  830.15887   626.70642   -159.47838  398.84872   239.96179   26.18988    705.74792   240.00320   17.65699    395.74753   220.35260   43.76863    705.08612   220.09315   35.88157    
10  0.075   578.22321   1549.22400  -222.32751  582.47699   1488.69202  -150.49860  563.50720   1428.02771  -358.16254  424.32901   1281.15295  -337.96259  504.69214   1037.35120  -449.92270  323.13589   924.39471   -317.57825  321.48663   719.16815   -192.81639  722.11450   1291.97229  -345.91641  827.04889   932.03326   -316.03214  829.22028   713.93781   -204.19936  461.00140   849.48938   -259.30951  725.35577   849.09351   -321.37314  538.43317   850.71783   -472.67126  413.98785   755.15033   -34.91985   356.80209   656.34241   38.76375    374.65222   460.17166   19.66212    394.75781   281.45157   -82.76581   444.49719   253.88823   -143.75554  398.84790   239.96207   46.18972    731.07086   747.40601   -44.43313   775.09540   630.83228   47.15326    748.70258   441.72873   -4.55191    717.07635   277.27521   -98.15665   662.74292   257.98560   -148.40193  705.75006   240.00217   37.65466    468.94724   621.91492   59.15485    474.79852   291.58649   -58.53809   661.32825   626.62622   66.28327    638.45538   292.72696   -63.11906   593.17859   849.29144   -290.34134  579.52557   849.73456   -348.49792  494.64462   757.53943   -329.27344  663.83142   757.28607   -368.99417  412.87466   639.12866   48.95930    718.21185   628.72925   56.71827    434.77817   286.51901   -70.65195   677.76587   285.00107   -80.63786   414.20035   641.45135   60.89395    714.51691   616.03503   66.98815    438.87769   275.22266   -66.25085   676.72290   283.62009   -73.62643   579.23804   757.41278   -349.13379  573.22174   1286.56262  -341.93948  320.82693   637.07751   -142.91167  830.08881   626.69965   -159.46625  398.84790   239.96207   26.18972    705.75006   240.00217   17.65466    395.74594   220.35304   43.76819    705.08551   220.09224   35.87900    
11  0.083   578.27698   1549.23279  -222.36746  582.52863   1488.72461  -150.52463  563.54028   1428.01013  -358.16925  424.32782   1281.14099  -337.94067  504.69028   1037.34753  -449.90952  323.14893   924.38000   -317.57095  321.50037   719.14282   -192.80624  722.11029   1291.93872  -345.93335  827.02594   932.00580   -316.06030  829.16455   713.92383   -204.19838  461.01395   849.49280   -259.29468  725.35895   849.08972   -321.36581  538.44214   850.72137   -472.65723  413.99179   755.15063   -34.90194   356.79398   656.34216   38.78064    374.65063   460.17209   19.67440    394.75494   281.45901   -82.77361   444.49719   253.89066   -143.75830  398.84579   239.96194   46.18934    731.09326   747.40674   -44.42930   775.12610   630.82587   47.15374    748.71252   441.73370   -4.56365    717.07404   277.27527   -98.15946   662.73987   257.99319   -148.39445  705.75134   240.00105   37.65257    468.94241   621.91534   59.17197    474.79074   291.58594   -58.54873   661.45306   626.63928   66.32295    638.45990   292.73703   -63.11698   593.18646   849.29126   -290.33026  579.53180   849.73541   -348.48477  494.65106   757.54517   -329.25894  663.83191   757.28723   -368.98447  412.86819   639.12872   48.97631    718.28961   628.73260   56.73835    434.77286   286.52249   -70.66117   677.76697   285.00613   -80.63822   414.19492   641.45233   60.90474    714.54431   616.03619   66.98418    438.87329   275.22855   -66.25517   676.72345   283.62436   -73.62563   579.24152   757.41620   -349.12170  573.21906   1286.53992  -341.93701  320.84094   637.04797   -142.90036  830.02002   626.69104   -159.45361  398.84579   239.96194   26.18934    705.75134   240.00105   17.65257    395.74323   220.35306   43.76741    705.08441   220.09123   35.87645    
12  0.092   578.33679   1549.24146  -222.40851  582.58752   1488.75647  -150.54962  563.57141   1427.99048  -358.17395  424.32373   1281.12537  -337.92090  504.68689   1037.34119  -449.89682  323.15894   924.36212   -317.56509  321.50897   719.11420   -192.79524  722.10205   1291.89807  -345.95346  827.00116   931.97491   -316.09143  829.10913   713.90796   -204.19771  461.02386   849.49304   -259.27960  725.36182   849.08575   -321.35577  538.45062   850.72327   -472.64114  413.99512   755.15106   -34.88120   356.78470   656.34204   38.80039    374.64792   460.17215   19.68953    394.75131   281.46768   -82.78207   444.49713   253.89374   -143.76071  398.84296   239.96175   46.18904    731.11365   747.40747   -44.42255   775.15424   630.82031   47.15828    748.72314   441.73746   -4.57037    717.07117   277.27734   -98.16243   662.73627   258.00171   -148.38629  705.75214   239.99992   37.65089    468.93488   621.91522   59.19133    474.78467   291.58798   -58.55484   661.55774   626.65295   66.36219    638.46393   292.74918   -63.11441   593.19287   849.28937   -290.31769  579.53711   849.73468   -348.47064  494.65680   757.54773   -329.24460  663.83313   757.28711   -368.97333  412.85980   639.12860   48.99586    718.35602   628.73663   56.76023    434.76797   286.52783   -70.66846   677.76758   285.01324   -80.63842   414.18823   641.45331   60.91844    714.57098   616.03577   66.98798    438.86786   275.23557   -66.25943   676.72357   283.62967   -73.62444   579.24500   757.41742   -349.10898  573.21289   1286.51172  -341.93719  320.84900   637.01501   -142.88730  829.95233   626.68121   -159.44023  398.84296   239.96175   26.18904    705.75214   239.99992   17.65089    395.73978   220.35303   43.76661    705.08331   220.09024   35.87412    
13  0.100   578.40186   1549.24963  -222.44949  582.65216   1488.78711  -150.57217  563.60022   1427.96936  -358.17603  424.31665   1281.10645  -337.90332  504.68170   1037.33264  -449.88440  323.16577   924.34155   -317.55978  321.51340   719.08319   -192.78366  722.08997   1291.85205  -345.97577  826.97473   931.94092   -316.12491  829.05396   713.89044   -204.19691  461.03174   849.49036   -259.26563  725.36426   849.08179   -321.34320  538.45795   850.72333   -472.62244  413.99768   755.15094   -34.85802   356.77472   656.34204   38.82266    374.64441   460.17136   19.70710    394.74734   281.47742   -82.79028   444.49695   253.89722   -143.76239  398.83994   239.96182   46.18920    731.13226   747.40826   -44.41296   775.18036   630.81519   47.16665    748.73407   441.74023   -4.57304    717.06799   277.28156   -98.16524   662.73102   258.01099   -148.37845  705.75275   239.99876   37.64967    468.92526   621.91455   59.21332    474.77927   291.59131   -58.55930   661.64301   626.66669   66.40018    638.46716   292.76270   -63.11161   593.19800   849.28607   -290.30441  579.54193   849.73242   -348.45618  494.66260   757.54755   -329.23114  663.83539   757.28607   -368.96078  412.84998   639.12830   49.01799    718.41168   628.74097   56.78341    434.76331   286.53436   -70.67479   677.76758   285.02213   -80.63842   414.18066   641.45410   60.93499    714.59686   616.03400   66.99803    438.86191   275.24338   -66.26311   676.72363   283.63617   -73.62258   579.24902   757.41681   -349.09598  573.20331   1286.47925  -341.93954  320.85245   636.97980   -142.87320  829.88562   626.67029   -159.42572  398.83994   239.96182   26.18920    705.75275   239.99876   17.64967    395.73602   220.35327   43.76623    705.08234   220.08920   35.87209    
14  0.108   578.47131   1549.25720  -222.48918  582.72076   1488.81641  -150.59117  563.62640   1427.94727  -358.17502  424.30673   1281.08459  -337.88788  504.67447   1037.32263  -449.87238  323.16913   924.31873   -317.55481  321.51459   719.05096   -192.77179  722.07440   1291.80212  -345.99945  826.94690   931.90399   -316.15976  828.99902   713.87122   -204.19559  461.03836   849.48492   -259.25415  725.36633   849.07819   -321.32889  538.46375   850.72144   -472.60077  413.99911   755.14996   -34.83310   356.76419   656.34222   38.84704    374.64035   460.16943   19.72668    394.74347   281.48779   -82.79732   444.49649   253.90088   -143.76306  398.83719   239.96240   46.19005    731.14905   747.40918   -44.40086   775.20471   630.81024   47.17823    748.74457   441.74203   -4.57294    717.06488   277.28775   -98.16759   662.72369   258.02081   -148.37170  705.75354   239.99753   37.64889    468.91440   621.91309   59.23785    474.77359   291.59470   -58.56438   661.71069   626.67944   66.43618    638.46930   292.77658   -63.10881   593.20233   849.28156   -290.29150  579.54688   849.72876   -348.44226  494.66934   757.54510   -329.21957  663.83923   757.28473   -368.94742  412.83929   639.12769   49.04244    718.45770   628.74481   56.80721    434.75854   286.54126   -70.68085   677.76709   285.03217   -80.63820   414.17230   641.45490   60.95416    714.62134   616.03156   67.01192    438.85605   275.25140   -66.26572   676.72375   283.64374   -73.61988   579.25427   757.41492   -349.08350  573.19055   1286.44336  -341.94366  320.85278   636.94385   -142.85858  829.81989   626.65808   -159.40991  398.83719   239.96240   26.19005    705.75354   239.99753   17.64889    395.73236   220.35406   43.76654    705.08191   220.08809   35.87038    
15  0.117   578.54474   1549.26416  -222.52641  582.79163   1488.84436  -150.60583  563.65009   1427.92480  -358.17072  424.29456   1281.06006  -337.87448  504.66501   1037.31177  -449.86102  323.16849   924.29376   -317.55075  321.51328   719.01855   -192.75987  722.05591   1291.74951  -346.02396  826.91803   931.86444   -316.19513  828.94458   713.85034   -204.19357  461.04453   849.47687   -259.24673  725.36804   849.07532   -321.31409  538.46777   850.71735   -472.57617  413.99902   755.14789   -34.80732   356.75308   656.34271   38.87311    374.63596   460.16629   19.74763    394.74002   281.49814   -82.80238   444.49548   253.90460   -143.76254  398.83502   239.96362   46.19165    731.16418   747.40997   -44.38670   775.22736   630.80518   47.19213    748.75439   441.74289   -4.57114    717.06213   277.29541   -98.16927   662.71423   258.03091   -148.36667  705.75476   239.99619   37.64857    468.90314   621.91058   59.26444    474.76743   291.59735   -58.57062   661.76318   626.69012   66.46952    638.47028   292.78989   -63.10616   593.20630   849.27606   -290.28043  579.55249   849.72382   -348.43018  494.67786   757.54053   -329.21106  663.84497   757.28351   -368.93417  412.82813   639.12665   49.06878    718.49524   628.74762   56.83083    434.75372   286.54776   -70.68650   677.76617   285.04266   -80.63772   414.16318   641.45605   60.97557    714.64423   616.02850   67.02810    438.85080   275.25903   -66.26697   676.72430   283.65210   -73.61635   579.26141   757.41205   -349.07260  573.17523   1286.40479  -341.94922  320.85120   636.90845   -142.84352  829.75519   626.64471   -159.39296  398.83502   239.96362   26.19165    705.75476   239.99619   17.64857    395.72910   220.35553   43.76763    705.08221   220.08687   35.86905    
16  0.125   578.62146   1549.27051  -222.56018  582.86310   1488.87097  -150.61574  563.67163   1427.90222  -358.16309  424.28073   1281.03333  -337.86313  504.65335   1037.30042  -449.85071  323.16330   924.26648   -317.54880  321.51001   718.98688   -192.74814  722.03491   1291.69495  -346.04880  826.88837   931.82245   -316.23038  828.89111   713.82758   -204.19090  461.05109   849.46643   -259.24460  725.36914   849.07306   -321.30042  538.46997   850.71112   -472.54938  413.99707   755.14453   -34.78153   356.74164   656.34332   38.90033    374.63120   460.16196   19.76893    394.73721   281.50763   -82.80502   444.49374   253.90822   -143.76080  398.83359   239.96545   46.19401    731.17749   747.41064   -44.37097   775.24823   630.79980   47.20747    748.76349   441.74289   -4.56809    717.06006   277.30377   -98.17017   662.70270   258.04086   -148.36380  705.75653   239.99477   37.64889    468.89230   621.90704   59.29242    474.76117   291.59912   -58.57715   661.80322   626.69775   66.49977    638.46979   292.80176   -63.10352   593.21014   849.26971   -290.27252  579.55890   849.71765   -348.42105  494.68863   757.53442   -329.20654  663.85223   757.28271   -368.92227  412.81696   639.12518   49.09637    718.52576   628.74878   56.85362    434.74918   286.55338   -70.69109   677.76489   285.05276   -80.63685   414.15329   641.45715   60.99905    714.66522   616.02496   67.04523    438.84653   275.26572   -66.26679   676.72546   283.66095   -73.61211   579.27045   757.40857   -349.06439  573.15784   1286.36414  -341.95596  320.84869   636.87506   -142.82788  829.69220   626.62964   -159.37511  398.83359   239.96545   26.19401    705.75653   239.99477   17.64889    395.72650   220.35759   43.76956    705.08307   220.08557   35.86839    
17  0.133   578.70099   1549.27661  -222.58966  582.93365   1488.89624  -150.62088  563.69147   1427.87964  -358.15237  424.26590   1281.00500  -337.85379  504.63986   1037.28857  -449.84186  323.15323   924.23657   -317.55035  321.50531   718.95642   -192.73692  722.01172   1291.63867  -346.07379  826.85815   931.77814   -316.26511  828.83917   713.80304   -204.18788  461.05914   849.45355   -259.24893  725.36926   849.07129   -321.28940  538.47040   850.70306   -472.52194  413.99319   755.13983   -34.75653   356.73016   656.34399   38.92785    374.62607   460.15659   19.78937    394.73529   281.51553   -82.80519   444.49127   253.91156   -143.75809  398.83289   239.96767   46.19708    731.18896   747.41101   -44.35427   775.26685   630.79407   47.22346    748.77185   441.74210   -4.56389    717.05878   277.31198   -98.17036   662.68945   258.05014   -148.36348  705.75867   239.99338   37.64999    468.88260   621.90240   59.32095    474.75476   291.59976   -58.58382   661.83362   626.70197   66.52674    638.46808   292.81174   -63.10058   593.21417   849.26245   -290.26917  579.56622   849.71027   -348.41599  494.70236   757.52734   -329.20712  663.86078   757.28265   -368.91302  412.80637   639.12323   49.12440    718.55023   628.74805   56.87510    434.74503   286.55765   -70.69450   677.76343   285.06186   -80.63547   414.14285   641.45819   61.02412    714.68402   616.02069   67.06272    438.84363   275.27087   -66.26540   676.72717   283.66977   -73.60751   579.28156   757.40503   -349.06006  573.13879   1286.32178  -341.96378  320.84613   636.84436   -142.81157  829.63159   626.61298   -159.35699  398.83289   239.96767   26.19708    705.75867   239.99338   17.64999    395.72464   220.36003   43.77228    705.08429   220.08429   35.86864
```

Here is a [**link**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6ChdzN8V40_cV9KdTZBTWJYT0k/view?usp=sharing) to the text file.

Comment: We cannot save that image as a text file. Provide it as text. And importing files as  separate matrices is not a good idea. As you said, you have hundreds of text files, creating hundreds of matrices would be very bad. Read why here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32467170/5698672

Comment: I will need to plot specific columns from each datafile (each file is for a unique research participant, and each of the columsn are timeseries), and sometimes will need to plot multiple participant's columns together in one plot. Since the files vary in length by a lot, I wasn't sure of a better solution. Any advice for a better method would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [**`dlmread`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html) will be better. Also for your case as you stated that *the files vary in length by a lot*, so using a cell array would be a better option.

```
hold on;
datacell = cell(numfiles,1);    %Pre-allocation
for k=1:numfiles
    datacell{k} = dlmread(txtfiles(k), '', 6, 0); %skipping 6 rows and zero columns
    plot(datacell{k}(:,5));     %to plot 5th column of each file
end
```

Comment: How would I plot, for example, the 5th column from each matrix within the datacell onto the same plot?