# How to pass multiple comment style to skip the header of a text file?

Tags: matlab, import, text-files

I am trying to read hundreds of .dat file by skipping header lines (I do not know how many of them I need to skip beforehand). Header lines very from 1 to 20 and have at beginning either or "$" oder "!".
A sample data (left column - node, right column - microstructure) has always two columns and looks like the following:

```
!===
!Comment
$Material
    1 1.452E-001
    2 1.446E-001
    3 1.459E-001
```

I tried the following codeline, assuming I know beforehand that there 3 lines in header:

```
fid = fopen('Graphite_Node_Test.dat') ;
data = textscan(fid,'%f %f','HeaderLines',3) ;
fclose(fid);
```

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44507648/how-to-skip-header-lines-while-importing-multiple-text-files) works if the number of header lines is known. How can I change the code so that it can read the .dat file without knowing the number of header lines beginning with either "$" or "!" sign?

Comment: With a for loop and `fgetl`

Comment: `textscan` has the option to treat lines as comments and skip them. Check the docs: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html#btg0kfb

Comment: textscan does not allow multiple comment style!

Comment: @Ander Biguri, thought about that, but with around 100 files and 100 000 lines in each "for" loop will be time consuming.

Comment: Alternatively, `fread` the entire thing, post-process it once loaded.

Comment: you could preprocess outside matlab, e.g. this took ~4.5s for 100 files with 500K rows each: `find . -iname '*.dat' -exec sed -i '/^[!$]/d' {} +`

Comment: The for loop (Ander mentioned) should of course have a `break` (i.e. use a while loop). Else I agree with `fread` solution.