# How to receive output of function in variable number of arrays in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, function, output

I want to receive the output of `[I_1,I_2,...,I_n] = ind2sub(siz,IND)` for an n-dimensional array with size of dimensions defined in `siz`. The linear index is a single value in `IND`. I know the number of elements in each dimension of the array. But the number of dimensions is variable (it is known but variable). I want to know how to receive the output of `ind2sub(siz,IND)` in variable number of arrays as it needs `n` number of arrays to receive the output.

In fact, the number of dimensions is number of attributes of data points in a data set. If data set is called `x` the number of dimensions is `size(x,2)`.

Comment: Using dynamic variable names is bad, [read this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32467170/5211833). Why don't you simply use a multidimensional array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To collect an arbitrary number of subscripted indices from [`ind2sub`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html), you'll want to use a [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) instead of individual variables like `I_1`, `I_2`, etc., to store the output. You can [capture the comma-separated list output](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html#br2js35-14) as follows, assuming your N-dimensional data is in a variable `x`:

```
[indices{1:ndims(x)}] = ind2sub(size(x), IND);
```

And `indices` will now be a 1-by-`ndims(x)` cell array containing the subscripts for each dimension that correspond to the linear indices in `IND`.