# Failing show legend

Tags: matlab, loops, plot

I have a huge amount of data to plot, and thanks to:

```
x=matlab.lang.makeValidName(strcat(...)); 
assignin('base',x,I);
```

for each loop of process, where I calculate `I`, I assign the value of `I` (a vector) to the variable name `I_Pnum1_Bnum2` where `num1` is the value of P and `num2` the value of B. So, at the end I have lots of `I`'s for:

```
num1=-4:-1:-14;
num2=[0 5 10 20:20:120 150 170 200 220];
```

That's why, for each value of P, I want to plot (on the same graph) all `I`'s for different B:

```
num1=-4:-1:-14;
num2=[0 5 10 20:20:120 150 170 200 220];
for i=1:length(num1)
    legend=[];
   figure(i)
   for j=1:length(num2)
       Y=matlab.lang.makeValidName(strcat('I_p',num2str(abs(num1(i))),'_B',num2str(double(num2(j)))));
       plot(V,eval(Y),'linewidth',2)
       hold on
       leg=strcat("B= ",num2str(b(j)));
       legend=[legend leg];
   end
   title(strcat("Caractéristiques I(V) @",num2str(p(i)),"dBm"))
   legend(legend);
end
clc;
```

**The problem**: I get

> Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'string'.

and it is due to the line legend(legende), and I don't understand why, because the vector legende is well defined.

Comment: You don't call `legend(legende)`, see your code. You call `legend(legend)`, which Georg's answer proofs is not a very smart idea. Don't call a sum `sum`,  a mean `mean`, or a legend `legend`. Or, in general terms: **don't use the names of build-in functions for your variables**.

Comment: What is also a very bad practise is using *Dynamic Variable Names*, meaning those things you created using `assignin` and evaluate using the dreaded `eval`. Doing this is very error-prone and makes your code very, very slow, see [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32467170/5211833) and references contained therein as to why. Just use a `cell` or `struct` which are purpose-build for this kind of thing without the huge downside of `eval`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because of a conflict between your variable named `legend` and the build-in MATLAB function `legend()`. Rename your variable to e.g. `leg1` then it should work as expected.