# Saving dynamically named variables in a for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, save

I have a 2x2 design research and I have over 150 participants. So I have 4 different conditions and I named them as `11`, `12`, `21`, `22`.

I need to transform all my cell values to matrices with `cell2mat` and need to do that for each participant. I am trying to write a `for` loop to have different values for each participant, but I could not figure out how to do it.

```
 %% each participant records

%conditions are = 11 , 12 , 21, 22
%participants 1:101 (p1,p2,p3.....p150)

for i = 1:150
%personal control (pc)
p_pc11= cell2mat(A.pc11(i,:));
p_pc12= cell2mat(A.pc12(i,:));
p_pc21= cell2mat(A.pc21(i,:));
p_pc22= cell2mat(A.pc22(i,:));

 save('p?_pc11' , p1_pc11)

end
```

It should be something like this but I do not know how to save each variable differently. I tried `p(i)_pc11  , p'i'_pc11`, but it gave errors. I need to have a unique variable for each participant. I am keeping them in structs but it is not good for running anova or manova.

So my question is, how can I save each participants value with different names?

Comment: Do you want to save the various variables *inside* MATLAB (bad, very bad), or *outside* MATLAB (easily done)?

Comment: why do you want to create a variable for each participant, and not just contain everything in a matrix. (row # is participant #)...

Comment: @Adriaan why saving inside the matlab is very bad?

Comment: @bla If I do that will it let me run manova with demogrpahics for each participant? Also I have lots of variables like pc such as offers, responses, reaction times etc...

Comment: You can just create an array of 150 zeros and fill it. For example, for the first one, before the loop you write  `p_pc11 = zeros(150,1)`, then the loop: `for i = 1:150 p_pc11(i)= cell2mat(A.pc11(i,:));`

Comment: @rvbarreto DON'T do that please. `zeros(a)` will create a square matrix of dimensions a-by-a, which is probably not what the OP wants. *Always* use two numbers within `zeros`, `ones`, `nan` etc, like `zeros(150,1)`, to make sure it ends up being the dimension you actually want it to be, and not something square and much larger than anticipated.

Comment: @Adriaan. Nice. zeros(150,1) then :)

Answer (score 2):

```
for ii = 1:150
%personal control (pc)
p_pc11= cell2mat(A.pc11(ii,:));
p_pc12= cell2mat(A.pc12(ii,:));
p_pc21= cell2mat(A.pc21(ii,:));
p_pc22= cell2mat(A.pc22(ii,:));

% Generate numbered filenames
filename11 = sprintf('p_pc11_%d',ii);
filename12 = sprintf('p_pc12_%d',ii);
filename21 = sprintf('p_pc21_%d',ii);
filename22 = sprintf('p_pc22_%d',ii);

% Save them with the numbered name
save(filename11 , p_pc11)
save(filename12 , p_pc12)
save(filename21 , p_pc21)
save(filename22 , p_pc22)

end
```

Use [`sprintf`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) to generate numbered filenames, then save those. Note that I changed your loop index from `i` to `ii`, as [`i` is the imaginary unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).

Note that using numbered variable names, or indeed any kind of dynamically named variable, inside of MATLAB is very, very bad for performance and readability, and thus debugging, issues, see [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32467170/5211833) and the references to MathWorks sources contained therein for a more in depth explanation.

Comment: thanks for your answer and recommendation! I was going to run some statistical analysis after I save each variable differently but it seems like not a good idea to do

Comment: I am storing all those variables in a struct, when i need to access them I can retrieve them by typing `A.pc11(1,:)` but I cannot run anova with them.  @Adriaan

Comment: @australopithecus I have no idea what anova is or how it works, so I can't help you there. If it's inside MATLAB: chuck in inside a `for` loop and get each structfield to a temporary variable, and thus out of the struct, before plugging it into anova. Don't try to save all 150 variable dynamically, that'll just mess up everything in your script.

Comment: I am going to try it! Thank you very much! I am a novice and a learner for matlab but now i can see a solution for my question thanks to your answer :)