# Matlab For Cycle, selecting variables named with incremental numbers

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have a number of vectors containing data that i have to elaborate in the same way, they are named in this fashion: "data1", "data2" ecc... I would like to automatize the process with a for cycle, how can i "select" iteratively the variables using the index? 
For example, the first line of my elaboration is an assignment like "x = data1", i want the second cycle to do "x = data2" and so on.
Thank you in advance

Comment: It's much better to define one array `data` containing all your current variables as rows, cells, or fields. [Dynamic variable names are bad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32467170/2586922). You should [keep data out of your variable names](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of `strcat` and `num2str` to create the name of the variable

```
i = 1;
name = strcat("data",int2str(i));
```

Thus putting it inside a for-loops which updates `i` will continuously change the name. Next you can use `eval` to evaluate the name

```
x = eval(name);
```

In total

```
for i = 1:n
    name = strcat("data",int2str(i));
    x = eval(name);
end
```

**NOTE 1:** It is in general considered bad practice to create variable names this way. You would have been much better off with saving all variables in the same array. As linked by Luis Mendo in the comments.

**NOTE 2:** It is generally recognised as a for-loop, not a for-cycle :D

Comment: Thank you the eval works, i named var like that becouse they are acquisition from a sensor.

Comment: @MatteoCaruso Your sensor automatically picks variable names? How can that be?