# Integrating over a constant function

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, numerical-integration

I am trying to integrate over a constant function in MATLAB 2017a, but I am stuck. First of all when I integrate using the following script, I get the right output. So the script works for a `x0` which depends on `t`.

```
function E=sol(n,k)
x0 = @(t)  t^(2);
j = 0;
E = zeros(n,1);
 while j < n+1 ;
    K = matlabFunction(subs(po(j,k))) ; 
    eval(sprintf('x%d = integral(K,0,1);',j+1)) ;
    E(j+1,1) = subs(sprintf('x%d',j+1))
    j = j+1;
 end
end
```

Where function `po(j,k)` is as follows,

```
function A_j = po(j,k)          % Adomian polynomials
 if j >0
  x =  sym('x',[1 j]);
    syms p;                            % Assinging a symbolic variable for p
    syms x0;
    S = x0+ sum(p.^(1:j) .* x) ;     % Sum of p*x up to order j
    Q =f(S,k);                        % Taking the k-th power of S, i.e. 
    A_nc = diff(Q,p,j)/factorial(j);  % Taking the j-th order derivative 
    A_j = subs(A_nc,p,0) ;            % Filling in p=0
 else
    syms x0;
    S = x0; 
    A_j =f(S,k);                      % Taking the k-th power of S,
  end
 end
```

And where `f(x,k)` is,

```
function F = f(x,k) % Nonlinear function of k power
 F = x^k ;
end
```

Now when I cal `sol(n,k)` it does work. But when I try to change my `x0` function in `sol(n,k)` in a constant function like,

```
function E=solcon(n,k)
x0 = @(t) 2.*ones(size(t));
j = 0;
E = zeros(n,1);
 while j < n+1 ;
    K = matlabFunction(subs(po(j,k))) ; 
    eval(sprintf('x%d = integral(K,0,1);',j+1)) ;
    E(j+1,1) = subs(sprintf('x%d',j+1))
    j = j+1;
 end
end
```

It does not work, As you can see I added `*ones(size(t));` just to make it a function of `t`. But unfortunately it still doesn't work when I call,

```
K = matlabFunction(subs(po(j,k))) ;
```

I get,

```
@()4.0
```

And then I get an error when I call,

```
eval(sprintf('x%d = integral(K,0,1);',j+1))
```

**Could anyone help me out trying to integrate over a constant?**

The error I get when I call `solcon(10,2)` is

```
Error using symengine>@()4.0
Too many input arguments.

Error in integralCalc/iterateScalarValued (line 314)
            fx = FUN(t);

Error in integralCalc/vadapt (line 132)
        [q,errbnd] = iterateScalarValued(u,tinterval,pathlen);

Error in integralCalc (line 75)
    [q,errbnd] = vadapt(@AtoBInvTransform,interval);

Error in integral (line 88)
Q = integralCalc(fun,a,b,opstruct);

Error in solcon1 (line 7)
eval(sprintf('x%d = integral(K,0,1);',j+1)) ;
```

EDIT 2
I used the following script,

```
function E=solcon(n,k)
x0 = @(t) 2.*ones(size(t));
j = 0;
E = zeros(n,1);
 while j < n+1 ;
    K = matlabFunction(subs(po(j,k))) ; 
    fstr= func2str(K)
    if fstr(3) == ')';
       x{j+1} = K*(1-0)
    else x{j+1} = integral(K,0,1)
    end
 E(j+1,1) = subs(x{j+1},1);
 j = j+1
 end
end
```

But the following error occurs,

```
Undefined operator '*' for input arguments of type 'function_handle'.
Error in solcone1 (line 9)
x{j+1} = K*(1-0);
```

Comment: It will not fix your problem , but definetly it will improve your programming and future headaches if you woudl just avoid using `eval` completely. Use `x{jj+1}`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am going to ignore the terrible choice of using `eval`, especially when you can do

```
x{j+1} = integral(K,0,1);
```

[Read more on why dynamic variables and eval are terrible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32467029/how-to-put-these-images-together/32467170#32467170)

---

Your problem is that `matlabFunction` is a smartass. When it detects that your function does not have any dependency to `x`, it gives you a function with empty input arguments `@()4.0`. As you see, `integral` does not like that.

A way of solving the problem is detecting this before calling `integral`. You could check if it has input arguments, and if it does not, then evaluate the integral "by hand"

```
 ...
 while j < n+1 ;

    K = matlabFunction(subs(po(j,k))) ; 
    fstr=func2str(K);
    if fstr(3)==')'
         x{j+1}=K()*(1-0); % evaluate the integral yourself
    else
         x{j+1} = integral(K,0,1);
    end
    E(j+1,1) = subs(x{j+1});
    j = j+1;
 end
...
```

---

The problem is considerably more difficult that I though I was. Either rewrite the entire thing, or using eval:

```
 ...
 while j < n+1 ;

    K = matlabFunction(subs(po(j,k))) ; 
    fstr=func2str(K);
    if j==0
          eval(sprintf('x%d = K()*(1-0);;',j+1)) ;
    else
          eval(sprintf('x%d = integral(K,0,1);',j+1)) ;
    end
     E(j+1,1) = subs(sprintf('x%d',j+1));
    j = j+1;
 end
...
```

Comment: I can't use these brackets in `x{j+1}` unless I specify a cell array. But my `x` isn't defined that way in `po`.

Comment: @Airapet A cell array is an array that contains whatever you want on it. In which way is your function specified so it is not within the "whatever you want" definition? `syms x;
f=x.^2;
g=@(x)(x^2);
a{1}=f;
a{2}=g;` works fine

Comment: When I call the function now I get the error which I posted under EDIT 2

Comment: @Airapet That is because you are a bit bad a copying :P. Its `K()` not `K`

Comment: Exactly what I said in the comment.......`x{j+1}=K()*(1-0);` NOT `x{j+1}=K*(1-0);`. `K` is a fucntion, you need to evaluate it, even if it has no inputs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172771/discussion-between-airapet-and-ander-biguri).

Comment: "I am going to ignore the terrible choice of using `eval`... but do read this link because I can't really ignore it at all." LOL!

Comment: @Cris it was that ir rewriting the entire thing, which I was la to do :p