# How can I define dynamically named matrices?

Tags: matlab

If you define a range from `A1` to `A10` in Excel using VBA you cam use `Range("A1:A10")`. On the other hand side it's possible to write down `Range("A1:A"&10)`. How can I use the second way in MATLAB, please?

I have some matrices `M1`, `M2`, `M3`, ..., and I wish to define them by using iterator `FOR` that helps me stop writing the matrix names completely.

Comment: This is called **Dynamic Variable naming** which is [bad, very bad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32467170/5211833). Don't name your variables like that. Either use sensible names per variable, or, if they are all the same but e.g. in different iterations of a program, use, in order of preference, a multi-dimensional matrix (if the sizes are equal), a `struct` with proper naming, or a `cell`.

Comment: Start with `M={M1,M2,M3,...}`, then you can iterate over the matrices with `M{index}`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Notwithstanding the comment that this approach is frowned upon, below is a way to do it programmatically:

```
% define cell with matrix names
number_of_matrices_I_want = 5;
my_matrix_names = repmat({'NA'}, 1, number_of_matrices_I_want);
for ii = 1:length(my_matrix_names)
    my_matrix_names(ii) = {strcat('M',num2str(ii))};    
end

% example for how to populate a matrix from "my_matrix_names"
x = rand(5,1); % fake numbers
y = rand(5,1);
eval([my_matrix_names{1} '=  [x y]']);
```