# How do I retain the number of arguments of a function handle when passing it to some other function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, arguments, function-handle

I am trying to write a function that takes a cell array of functions as an input and that outputs the same functions, but in a somewhat different format.

Specifically, I want a row vector, of say length `N`, of functions `fVec = [f1(x, y, z), f2(x,y,z), ..., fn(x, y, z)]` all of which always output a column vector of the same length, say `M`. Now I want the evaluation of `fVec(x, y, z)` to output an `MXN` matrix, where each column represents the output of its corresponding vector.

However, because Matlab doesn't accept regular function handle arrays, it must be done using cell arrays. (, right?)

Moreover, I want a general function that works for several sets of functions, that don't necessarily have three inputs. That is, I want the function `fVec(1, ..., x) = [f1(1, ..., x), f2(1, ..., x), fn(1, ..., x)]`, meaning that each of the funtions `f1, f2, fn` always have the same number of inputs.

Therefore, I need some function that takes as an input a cell array of function handles `{f1(1, ..., x), f2(1, ..., x), fn(1, ..., x)}` and outputs some overarching function `fVec(1, ..., x)`.

I already tried writing a function that I thought should do this:

```matlab
function overArchingFunction = transformFunctionArray(functionArray)
    if length(functionArray) == 1
        if isa(functionArray, 'cell')
            overArchingFunction = functionArray{:};
        else
            overArchingFunction = functionArray;
        end
    else
        disp(cellfun(@(fun) fun(x), functionArray, ...
                'UniformOutput', false))
        overArchingFunction = @(vars) cell2mat(cellfun(@(fun) fun(vars), functionArray, ...
                'UniformOutput', false));
    end
end
```

This works for "arrays of length 1", obviously. However, there is a problem with this code. Let's make a test function, say `testfun = @(a, b, c, d, e) a(:,3) - a(:,2)` (where testfun is a function of `b, c, d, e` to replicate the most general scenario), and make an array of this function, `functionArray = {testfun, testfun}`.

Now we call our function `overArchingFunction = transformFunctionArray(functionArray)`. However, when calling `solution = transfun([[10 1 2]; [3 4 5]], 0, 0, 0, 0)`, I want the output to be:

```matlab
solution =

     1     1
     1     1
```

This is not the case, because with the `@(vars)` and `fun(vars)` statements, I'm restricting the number of input variables to this function to only one variable, whereas I am trying to pass five arguments (namely `[[10 1 2]; [3 4 5]], 0, 0, 0, 0`). I though I'd fix this by replacing `vars` with 
`varargin`, but this gives me the error:

```matlab
Attempt to execute SCRIPT varargin as a function:
/MATLAB/toolbox/matlab/lang/varargin.m
```

Summarising, how do I retain the original number of input arguments of `f1, f2, ..., fn` in the `overArchingFunction`?

Comment: How about just passing a `struct` between functions, with all your arguments as fields?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm building on top of (inaccessible and thus immutable) existing code where the arguments are strictly passed as "loose" arguments. Therefore, I'd like to stay as close to the existing code as possible and try to accept the arguments in the manner I described above.

Comment: Not a complete duplicate, but certainly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58143196/summation-of-n-function-handles-in-matlab

Comment: My comment here is the same: not everything needs to be an anonymous function. This problem is easy to solve with a regular function using `varargin`.

Comment: By the way: did you run the code? `overArchingFunction = functionArray{:};` should give you an error message.

Comment: I agree with you on that point; I don't necessarily want `testfun` in my above example to be anonymous. However, in this example, it doesn't matter whether `testfun` is anonymous or not; it is the declaration of the input arguments to `overArchingFunction` that's the bottleneck. I.e., in the function definition of `overArchingFunction`, I'm using a non-anonymous function that still has the `varargin` problem.

Comment: I did run the code and I didn't run into an error at that point. Running either 
`mytestfun = @(a, b, c, d, e) a(:,3) - a(:,2);
transfun = transformFunctionArray(mytestfun)`
or 
`mytestfun = @(a, b, c, d, e) a(:,3) - a(:,2);
transfun = transformFunctionArray({mytestfun})`
doesn't result in any errors for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. The answer indeed lay in using `varargin`. However, because `varargin` passes a cell structure input, you need to access those cells' contents by using `varargin{:}`. The function should thus be:

```matlab
function overArchingFunction = transformFunctionArray(functionArray)
    if length(functionArray) == 1
        if isa(functionArray, 'cell')
            overArchingFunction = functionArray{:};
        else
            overArchingFunction = functionArray;
        end
    else
        overArchingFunction = @(varargin) cell2mat(cellfun(@(fun) fun(varargin{:}), 
            functionArray, ...
                'UniformOutput', false));
    end
end
```

Such that the following commands give the required answer.

```matlab
>> testfun = @(a, b, c, d, e) a(:,3) - a(:,2)

testfun =

  function_handle with value:

    @(a,b,c,d,e)a(:,3)-a(:,2)

>> transfun = transformFunctionArray({mytestfun, mytestfun})

transfun =

  function_handle with value:

    @(varargin)cell2mat(cellfun(@(fun)fun(varargin{:}),functionArray,'UniformOutput',false))

>> myans = transfun([[10 1 2]; [3 4 5]], 0, 0, 0, 0)

myans =

     1     1
     1     1
```