# assigning into an array within cell array

Tags: matlab, cell-array

say I have got two cell arrays *a*, *b*:

```
for k=1:3
    a{k} = nan(3, k);
end
b = {ones(1, 1), ones(1, 2), ones(1, 3)};
```

how I assign each cell in *b* into the second line of each cell of *a*?

Comment: I truly appreciate your effort but it did not work for me. I have upvoted your comment...

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `it did not work`?

Answer (score 1):

Just have a loop:

```
for i=1:size(a,2)
    a{i}(2,:) = b{i}
end
```

If `a` and `b` are small, you can use [deal](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html):

```
[a{1}(2,:) a{2}(2,:) a{3}(2,:)] = deal(b{:});
```

Comment: this is answering my question but considering that I am asking a minimal question, would it solve a case where k=1:50?

Comment: Although I honestly think you should just do a simple loop

Comment: I dont feel good with the eval solution but you are probably right about the loop solution.

Comment: I just wanted to show that that is one option. I personally don't see an alternative to this or the loop. I don't think you are going to find a different "magic" oneliner. Assigning stuff to comma separated outputs in this scenario is tricky.

Comment: I'd be very cautious with suggesting `eval`, especially without any warnings. See [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32467170/5211833) and references therein on why it's best to avoid it whenever possible. Gist is: hard to debug errors and slow execution due to disabling of the JIT.

Comment: Of course, its just for fun. OP should just have a loop, since that is the simplest and most readable solution.