# Loop and vary the name of a list by concatenation on matlab

Tags: matlab, loops

I have 5 lists named liste_1, liste_2,..,liste_5. The goal is to loop on i to make calculations on the different lists:

For i=1:5

```
  signal=liste_i
```

Then, I'd like to have the possibility to manipulate signal in the loop.

Comment: Use `list(1)` to `list(5)` in a normal array for same-size elements, or a cell array for different sizes.

Comment: To expand on @beaker's comment: What you want to do is called _dynamic variables_, and [should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32467170/2586922)