# Count up variable/table name with while loop

Tags: matlab, loops, while-loop, matlab-table

I'm reading multiple tables with the same measurement variable. I want to compare the variables of tables with each other. Because there are so many tables and with each one I'm doing the same things, I wanted to automate the process with a while loop. But I don't know how to replace the `1` (in the variable and the table) with the `k`.

```matlab
data_1 = readtable('file_xy')
data_2 = readtable('file_zy')
data_3 = readtable('file_zz')
...

k=1

while k < 50
 Temp_1 = mean([data_1.tempx(:), data_1.tempz(:)], 2)
 p_1 = mean([data_1.px(:), data_1.pz(:)], 2)
 k = k+1
end
```

How can I read and process all my tables automatically?

Answer (score 2):

As you've noticed, copying lines of codes tens (let alone hundreds or thousands) of times to do the same thing can (and should!) be automated in most cases. What you're doing is creating *dynamic variable names*, [which is bad, very bad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32467170/5211833), not to mention requiring you to copy-paste the same line of code 50 times. Instead, read all files using a simple loop.

There're several other, smaller, points of improvement, I'll outline them below in the code block.

```matlab
% First, select the directory where your files are
input_dir = "C:\path\to\your\folder";
% Read the entire directory, searching for files of your type
% change .txt to whatever file type you have.
file_list = dir([input_dir '\*.txt']);

% ROWS comes from the amount of rows in your table files
% Pre-allocate output arrays for memory efficiency
Temp = zeros(ROWS, numel(file_list));
p = zeros(ROWS, numel(file_list));

% Use a for loop, since you know how many elements there are
for idx = 1:numel(file_list)
    % Read the files in order
    tmp_data = readtable([input_dir file_list(idx).name)]);
    Temp(:,idx) = mean([tmp_data .tempx(:), tmp_data .tempz(:)], 2)
    p(idx,:) = mean([tmp_data .px(:), tmp_data .pz(:)], 2)
end
```

`Temp` and `p` are now both matrices, with your original `Temp_1` in `Temp(:,1)`, `p_1` in `p(:,1)` etc. This assumes `Temp` and `p` to be rows, as per the dimensional argument in `mean`.

You might have to play around with the dimensions, as I don't know your data size. But in general, this should give you a good starting point on how to read multiple files and store them efficiently, using preallocation.
Note that whilst you can use a `while` loop, given that you have a fixed number of iterations, being the number of files, there's not much need to. I'd only use a `while` loop if the number of iterations is not fixed, for example in optimisation problems, where the code stops based on reaching some condition.

Finally: MATLAB has [great documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/) including lots of examples. If you don't understand a function, go to there as a first point of access.

Good luck!