# summing fields in struct arrays that have the same inner structure

Tags: matlab, struct, vectorization

I have many mat files, each contains a struct array `s` that has the same inner structure. Here is a minimal example for one of these `s` structure array that you'd get from loading a single file:

```
s(1).A.a=rand(3);
s(1).A.b=rand(4);
s(1).B  =1;

s(2).A.a=rand(3);
s(2).A.b=rand(4);
s(2).B  =10;
```

in practice the structure array has 100's of elements, and tens of fields and sub-fields. Please dont comment about the choice of saving the files the way they are. it is not in my control, and the question here is about how to deal with the information in these files.

I would like eventually to average all the information of each of the sub-fields of these structure arrays, so for that a logical step is to sum them (and then divide by the number of files) .

A solution I have at the moment is this:

```
% initialize arrays of the same inner structure as `s`      

 sum_s_A_a=zeros(size(s(1).A.a,1),size(s(1).A.a,2),numel(s));
 sum_s_A_b=zeros(size(s(1).A.b,1),size(s(1).A.b,2),numel(s));
 sum_s_B=zeros(1,numel(s));

 for jj=1:100 % loop over all 100 files (just for the example) 
   
       %  load here each file that contains s
    
      for ii=1:numel(s) ; % loop each element in s and add it to sum_s
        sum_s_A_a(:,:,ii) = sum_s_A_a(:,:,ii)  + s(ii).A.a;
        sum_s_A_b(:,:,ii) = sum_s_A_b(:,:,ii)  + s(ii).A.b;
        sum_s_B(ii) =  sum_s_B(ii) + s(ii).B;
      end

  end
```

This is extremely not practical as there are dozens of fields and sub-fields in `s`,  but **the minimal example above works for a the "single file" case if you use `s` as defined above**

I'd like to just sum the information over all these files in a similar way to the for loop above, but without writing down and hard code all the names of fields and sub-fields into array names, and if possible without the for loop.

I don't mind if the final container for the information is struct, cell or arrays.

Comment: What would be the type of the result? struct or numeric array?

Comment: ***WARNING*** you're using dynamic variable names, which is [bad, very bad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32467170/5211833). Don't call your variables `s1, s2, s3` etc. If possible, go back to the point where you create all those variables (which was probably a mess to begin with) and rethink your approach. Probably a superceding structure, or cell, would be preferable. You can then just index into that, rather than trying to go deeper into the rabbit hole that is dynamic variable naming.

Comment: I am actually not, this is just the example I gave. In reality I am reading mat files with the same name `s` and I just want to sum all the 100s of mat files in a the way described in the question.

Comment: I also dont understand why the question is closed. there is a minimal example, the details are clear. the question is about summing fields in structs that have the same inner structure.

Comment: I edited the question , the minimal example works, and I simplified and clarified the question as far as I possibly could.

Comment: The answer uses `fieldnames` to list the fields and iterate over them.

Comment: using the answer below on the minimal example I get this error :

Error using fieldnames
Invalid input argument of type 'double'. Input must be a structure or a Java or COM object.

Error in structsum_script>sumfields (line 48)
  fnames = fieldnames(s);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with your example in order to sum all `A` fields and to return a numeric array here is a way that doesn't use loop:

```
function result = sumstruct (varargin)
  v = [varargin{:}];
  s = [v.A];
  result = sum([s.tot1], 2);
end
```

and call it as:

```
result = sumstruct (s1, s2, s3);
```

EDIT:

However if you want also to sum other fields and their sub-fields and combine them to a struct you need to use loop or `cellfun`. Here is a solution that recursively reduces a nested structure:

```
function result = reduce(fcn, varargin)
  fcns0 = {@(x)cat(3, x{:}), @(x)x};
  switcher0 = @(tf, s)fcns0{tf+1}(s);
  fcns = {@(s)fcn(s), @(s)reduce(fcn, s{:})};
  switcher = @(tf, s)fcns{tf+1}(s);
  c = cellfun(@(x){struct2cell(x)}, varargin);
  s0 = cat(3, c{:});
  s1 = reshape(s0, [], numel(varargin));
  s2 = cellfun(@(x){switcher0(isstruct(x{1}), x)}, num2cell(s1, 2));
  s3 = reshape(s2, size(c{1}));
  s4 = cellfun(@(c){switcher(iscell(c), c)}, s3);
  fnames = fieldnames(varargin{1});
  result = cell2struct(s4, fnames, 1);
end
```

The first argument is a function handle to be used for the reduction and the remaining arguments are struct arrays.

Use a loop to load all of files and use reduce:

```
c = cell (1, 100);
for i = 1:100
  c{i} = load('file');
end
result = reduce(@(x)sum(x, 3), c{:});
result = reduce(@(x)x ./ 100, result);
```

Alternatively you can incrementally load files and perform reduce:

```
result = [];
for i = 1:100
  s = load('file');
  if i == 1
    result = s;
  else
    result = reduce(@(x)sum(x, 3), result, s);
  end
end  
result = reduce(@(x)x ./ 100, result);
```

Note that here the reduction function should perform along the third dimension of an array and because of that it has been written as `sum(x, 3)`.

Comment: thank you for the answer, unfortunately it will not work for me as it assumes a specific field or sub-field structure. I edited the question and added a minimal example where your code unfortunately doesn't work.

Comment: using the minimal example with your answer as follows: 
`c={s,s};
result = sumstruct (c{:});`
yields the error ( my script is structsum_script): `Error using fieldnames
Invalid input argument of type 'double'. Input must be a structure or a Java or COM object. Error in structsum_script>sumfields (line 48)
  fnames = fieldnames(s); Error in structsum_script>@(f){sumfields(v,f)} (line 42)
  c = cellfun(@(f){sumfields(v, f)}, fnames); Error in structsum_script>sumstruct (line 42)
  c = cellfun(@(f){sumfields(v, f)}, fnames); Error in structsum_script (line 37)
result = sumstruct (c{:});`

Comment: I edited the answer and I think it should work in more general cases.

Comment: again thank you for the edited answer, i really appreciate your help but I am afraid that you missed one of the points of the question ,  For example, in your answer,  if I have a case of the same input as in my question one after the other `c{1}=s` and `c{2}=s`  in your answer the `result.B=6`  you actually also summed over the elements of `s`. The desired answer is what you;'ll see for `sum_s_B`  in my question for that case. which is  a 2-elemnt array `sum_s_B = [ 2     4]`

Comment: Answer updated! It should now work based on your clarifications.