# Is there a matlab function for splitting an array for several array?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I want to split an array into several arrays automatically. For example:

```
a=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
b=[2 5]
```

Thus, I want to split it to:

```
c1=[1 2]
c2=[3 4 5]
c3=[6 7 8 9]
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way is to use [`mat2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html):

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9];
b = [2 5];
c = mat2cell(a, 1, diff([0 b numel(a)]));
```

This gives a cell array `c` containing the subarrays of `a`:

```
>> celldisp(c)
c{1} =
     1     2
c{2} =
     3     4     5
c{3} =
     6     7     8     9
```

Comment: I got it, thank you for you help!

Comment: Hello, I have another question. If I want to convert cell to array, how to do it? I look forward to hearing you, thank you!

Comment: @廖智宇 Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you mean. In my code, `c` is a [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html). You can access the individual pieces of your original array with curly-brace indexing: `c{1}` etc. Does that help?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know how to access cell array. But I want to achieve like c1=[1 2]. Now I solved it, thank you!

Comment: BTW, I have another question about array. b=[2 5]; c1=[1 2]; c2=[3 4 5]; c3=[6 7 8 9]; Since b(1,1) and b(1,2) belong to c1 and c2, how can I get it by MATLAB function? I look forward to hearing you, thank you!

Comment: @廖智宇 You probably want [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.ismember.html). Not also that dynamic variables (such as `c1`, `c2` instead of a cell array `c`) are almost always [not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32467170/2586922)