# How to put non repeated elements of a matrix into a row vector?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

I have 571 matrices (625x625) . all the matrices are symmetric with names of z1,z2,...z571;
I need to put non repeated elements of each matrix in a row vector. for example by putting non
repeated elements of z1 in a row vector I make row vector c1. making c2 from z2 ,...
this is my code for making c1 from z1:

```
c1=zeros(1,195625);
z1=zeros(625);
for i=1:625
    for j=1:625
        if (i<=j)
            z1(i,j)=c1(1,n);
            n=n+1;
        end
    end
end
```

first question is it takes long time to run. is there any way to enhence the speed?
second question: If I want to make c1 from z1, c2 from z2 ,... c571 from z571 and make a matrix called X with the rows of c1,c2,...,c571, what should I do?
Thank you for your help

Comment: For the second part: what you currently have is dynamic variable names, and it's a [bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32467170/2586922). It's better to pack all those matrices into a cell array, or better yet into a 3D array (of size 625x625x571 ). That makes looping or vectorization easier

Answer (score 1):

You can make your code much faster by pre-computing which elements you want and then using logical indexing to grab them all at once:

```
% Make symmetric matrix
matrixsize = 625;
z = rand(matrixsize);
z = z + z';

% Compute unique elements
uniqueelements = tril(true(size(z,1)));

% Pull unique elements from matrix
c = z(uniqueelements);
% Transpose to turn c from a column into a row.
c = c';
```

And then place each into your rows:

```
numMatrices = 571;
X = zeros(numMatrices,numel(c1));
for n = 1:numMatrices
    X(n,:) = % However you're dynamically referencing your c variables
end
```

If you store your matricies in one 3-dimensional array as per Luis's comment, you can still perform your operation all at once, and you get the X array for free:

```
matrixsize = 625;
numMatrices = 571;

zs = rand(matrixsize,matrixsize,numMatrices);
zs = zs + pagetranspose(zs);

uniqueelements = tril(true(size(zs,1)));
numElementsPerMatrix = sum(uniqueelements,"all");
uniqueelements = repmat(uniqueelements,1,1,size(zs,3));

cs = reshape(zs(uniqueelements),numElementsPerMatrix,size(zs,3));
cs = cs';
```

Note: `tril` rather than `triu` is used because MATLAB returns elements from logical indexing in column-major order, while your original loop was traversing the matrix in row-major order.

Comment: It is probably more efficient to use `tril` than `meshgrid` to figure out which elements to grab.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks for the tip, I didn't know `tril` existed. I'll edit my answer above.  It also grabs the bottom half rather than the top half, sweeping the row-major vs column-major order difference of `meshgrid` under the rug.

Comment: And, I immediately put my foot in my mouth, since I still have to explain the choice of `tril` rather than `triu`.