# How do I use part of variable name in a for loop in Matlab?

Tags: string, loops, matlab, eval

I'm new to Matlab and struggling to use part of a variable name in a loop.

This is my code currently

```
pp = 4;
for p = 1:pp

   % find corresponding timestamps
   corresponding_sd(p).t = intersect(double(psi_rad_sd(p).time), double(theta_rad_sd(p).time));
   corresponding_base(p).t = intersect(double(psi_rad_base(p).time), double(theta_rad_base(p).time));

   % only include the data from corresponding timestamps 
   corresponding_sd(p).psi_rad = psi_rad_sd(p).value(ismember(psi_rad_sd(p).time, corresponding_sd(p).t)); 
   corresponding_base(p).psi_rad = psi_rad_base(p).value(ismember(psi_rad_base(p).time, corresponding_base(p).t));
   corresponding_sd(p).theta_rad = theta_rad_sd(p).value(ismember(theta_rad_sd(p).time, corresponding_sd(p).t)); 
   corresponding_base(p).theta_rad = theta_rad_base(p).value(ismember(theta_rad_base(p).time, corresponding_base(p).t));
end
```

It works, but there are a lot of similar lines of code. As I need to use this approach for many other variables as well, I would like to put the '_sd' and '_base' parts in an extra for loop. I tried doing this by using the eval function, but my approach failed (and I also read that it is discouraged to use this function).
Can someone offer a solution?

To be clear, as a result I would like to have two 1x4 structs (corresponding_sd and corresponding_base), each with 3 fields (t, psi_rad, theta_rad). Each particpiant (in this example 4) should represent one row within the two output structs.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Instead of `corresponding_sd(p)` and `corresponding_base(p)` do `corresponding(s,p)`, where `s` is 1 for “sd” and 2 for “base”.

Comment: Thank you for your proposed solution, but I don't understand how it could work. I implemented it like this: 

`condition = ["_sd" "_base"];
for p = 1:4
    for c = 1:length(condition);
    corresponding(c,p).t = intersect(double(psi_rad(c,p).time), double(theta_rad(c,p).time));
end
end`

Comment: You shouldn't use dynamic variable names, [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32467170/2586922)'s why; see also [here](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html). Use arrays instead, where one of teh array dimensions corresponds to the "variable name"